# SQL convert date when select

Tags: sql, select

When selecting the data, I want the document date (belgetarihi) format to be just like the due date (vadetarihi). How to convert? Please help

```
SELECT 
    ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.*, 
    ORT_DOSYALAR_kayitdamga AS DSY_kayitdamga,
    HP.ID HP_ID,
    HP.planadi HP_planadi,
    KP.ID KP_ID,
    KP.planadi KP_planadi,
    ICE_CARIBANKA.ID CBANKA_ID,
    ICE_CARIBANKA.kod CBANKA_kod,
    ICE_CARIBANKA.hesapnr CBANKA_hesapnr,
    ICE_CARIBANKA.subenr  CBANKA_subenr,
    ICE_CARIBANKA.subeadi CBANKA_subeadi
FROM 
    ICE_ODEMEBASLIK WITH (NOLOCK)  
LEFT JOIN 
    ORT_PLAN AS HP WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.plankod = HP.plankod
LEFT JOIN 
    ORT_PLAN AS KP WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.karsiplankod = KP.plankod
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         ORT_DOSYALAR.kayitdamga AS ORT_DOSYALAR_kayitdamga  
     FROM 
         ORT_DOSYALAR WITH (NOLOCK)   
     WHERE 
         ORT_DOSYALAR.tablo = 6) AS DOSYA ON ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.kayitdamga = ORT_DOSYALAR_kayitdamga
LEFT JOIN 
    ICE_CARIBANKA WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICE_CARIBANKA.kayitdamga = ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.UQ_caribanka
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.IOdurum = -1
    AND ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.odemetipi = 1
    AND ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.pin = 0
    AND ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.belgetarihi >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2022', 103)
    AND ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.belgetarihi < CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2023', 103)
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.belgetarihi, 103),
    ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.IDfisbaslik,ICE_ODEMEBASLIK.vadetarihi
```

[here image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H1Zy.png)

Comment: hint ```TRUNC```

Comment: Hint: CAST as DATE : https://stackoverflow.com/a/467132/313663