# T-SQL to trim a datetime to the nearest date?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

**Duplicate of** *[What's the BEST way to remove the time portion of a datetime value (SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775)*

I have a column that tracks when things are created using a datetime, but I'd like to generate a report that groups them by day, so I need a way of nulling out the time component of a datetime column.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way is to change `getdate()` to your column name,

```
select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())+0, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think the +0 is required (at least using sql server 2012+).  This is the most creative and useful answer I've seen.

Answer (score 42):

Why not convert straight to date:

```
select convert(date, getdate())
```

This truncates days, not rounds.  To round Days do this:

```
select convert(date, getdate() + 0.5)
```

Comment: Easily the best answer for its simplicity and clarity.

Comment: Not if you are using SqlServer 2005

Comment: @nalply because SQL Server 2005 doesn't have the *date* data type

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution:

```
SELECT CAST( FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS float) ) AS smalldatetime)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way to get the date (as a string) from a datetime:

```
convert(varchar, <the date field/value/etc>, 101)
```

But note that ordering on this field will be alphabetical rather than by date since it's now a string

Answer (score 2):

I simply do cast(getdate() as date)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There are many formats to choose from so I'll link it instead.

http://library.cirr.com/Microsoft/SQL-Server-v7/html/ca-co_1.htm

If you wish to zero out the time like your post implies, you can try this:

```
select cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) as datetime)
```

Comment: convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getdate(), 101))

Comment: broken link.  New link for the page http://library.cirr.com/Microsoft/SQL-Server-v7/html/ca-co_1.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @CurrentDate datetime
set @CurrentDate = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

--or--

```
select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, MyDateColumn), 0) as DateOnly
from tblX
```

Answer (score 0):

In my searches I came across the following solution, it strips time out of UTC time only, but I found it interesting, so I thought someone else would too:

```
FUNCTION TrimDate(@dt AS DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(CAST((@dt - 0.500000038580247) AS INT) AS DATETIME) 
END
```

I would presume that it runs quickly since all it's doing is rounding and casting.