# SQL Server 2008 Group results in 24 hour range (from 10:01:00am to 10:00:59am)

Tags: sql, datetime, count, group-by, range

This question is related to SQL Server 2008.

I have a range of dates and need to count all dates within a 24 hour period between 10:01:00 AM and 10:00:59 AM.

I have the loop response ready to go for each day, but I can't figure out the right SQL statement to set the start and end times in the 24 hour range. Can someone please assist?

**Current SQL Statement**

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate), 10) as DailyDate, 
    COUNT(*) As Total
FROM 
    EndDate
WHERE 
    DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate) > getDate()
    AND DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate) < DateAdd(day, 10, getDate())
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate), 10)
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate), 10)
```

**Desired Output**

```
DailyDate - Total  
06-28-14 - ? *(should be 6)*  
06-29-14 - ? *(should be 13)*  
06-30-14 - ? *(should be 15)*  
07-01-14 - ? *(should be 8)*  
07-02-14 - ? *(should be 1)*
```

**SOURCE**

```
EndDate  
6/28/2014 8:23:00 PM  
6/29/2014 12:37:00 AM  
6/29/2014 2:56:00 AM  
6/29/2014 9:31:00 AM  
6/29/2014 10:00:00 AM  
6/29/2014 10:00:00 AM  

6/29/2014 10:01:00 AM  
6/29/2014 11:30:00 AM  
6/29/2014 1:09:00 PM  
6/29/2014 1:47:00 PM  
6/29/2014 6:01:00 PM  
6/29/2014 11:02:00 PM  
6/29/2014 11:33:00 PM  
6/30/2014 1:12:00 AM  
6/30/2014 3:37:00 AM  
6/30/2014 5:23:00 AM  
6/30/2014 5:24:00 AM  
6/30/2014 6:25:00 AM  
6/30/2014 10:00:00 AM  

6/30/2014 10:01:00 AM  
6/30/2014 10:02:00 AM  
6/30/2014 10:02:00 AM  
6/30/2014 11:11:00 AM  
6/30/2014 12:04:00 PM  
6/30/2014 5:15:00 PM  
6/30/2014 6:08:00 PM  
6/30/2014 9:51:00 PM  
6/30/2014 10:45:00 PM  
7/1/2014 12:14:00 AM  
7/1/2014 12:21:00 AM  
7/1/2014 2:32:00 AM  
7/1/2014 2:58:00 AM  
7/1/2014 6:30:00 AM  
7/1/2014 10:00:00 AM  

7/1/2014 12:40:00 PM  
7/1/2014 2:35:00 PM  
7/2/2014 12:04:00 AM  
7/2/2014 12:36:00 AM  
7/2/2014 2:34:00 AM  
7/2/2014 5:03:00 AM  
7/2/2014 6:14:00 AM  
7/2/2014 10:00:00 AM  

7/2/2014 10:01:00 AM
```

Comment: My first step would be to create a derived result that normalized the times to days, e.g. `select DateAdd(hour, -10, EndDate) as normDate, * from EndDate` .. then inspect the offsets and, if correct, use the derived query. (I believe the offset should be -10 hours, not +10 hours; using a derived relation will easily make this apparent - plus it will cut down on all the repeated typing.)

Comment: After the normalization, consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538412/t-sql-to-trim-a-datetime-to-the-nearest-date (which can itself be moved into the derived table suggested)

Comment: I was able to start the range at 10:01am by subtracting 601 minutes (10h 1m).

I replaced  

    DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate)  
with  

    DateAdd(minute, -601, EndDate)

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract 10 hours from the results.  Assuming that `EndDate` is `datetime`, you can do this by subtracting 10.0/24 days:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(CHAR(8), EndDate - 10.0/24, 10) as DailyDate, COUNT(*) As Total
FROM EndDate
WHERE DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate) > getDate() AND
      DateAdd(hour, 10, EndDate) < DateAdd(day, 10, getDate())
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(8), EndDate - 10.0/24, 10)
ORDER BY DailyDate;
```

The issue with your query is that you are adding 10 hours rather than subtracting 10 hours, so you could just modify your query as well and use `-10` for the `dateadd()`.