# How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In an extract I am dealing with, I have 2 `datetime` columns. One column stores the dates and another the times as shown.

How can I query the table to combine these two fields into 1 column of type `datetime`?

**Dates**

```
2009-03-12 00:00:00.000
2009-03-26 00:00:00.000
2009-03-26 00:00:00.000
```

**Times**

```
1899-12-30 12:30:00.000
1899-12-30 10:00:00.000
1899-12-30 10:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can simply add the two.

- **if** the `Time part` of your `Date` column is always zero
- **and** the `Date part` of your `Time` column is also always zero *(base date: January 1, 1900)*

Adding them returns the correct result.

```
SELECT Combined = MyDate + MyTime FROM MyTable
```

#### Rationale (kudos to ErikE/dnolan)

> It works like this due to the way the date is stored as two 4-byte
>   `Integers` with the left 4-bytes being the `date` and the right
>   4-bytes being the `time`. Its like doing `$0001 0000 + $0000 0001 =
>   $0001 0001`

#### Edit regarding new SQL Server 2008 types

`Date` and `Time` are types introduced in `SQL Server 2008`. If you insist on adding, you can use `Combined = CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME)`

#### Edit2 regarding loss of precision in SQL Server 2008 and up (kudos to Martin Smith)

Have a look at [How to combine date and time to datetime2 in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server) to prevent loss of precision using SQL Server 2008 and up.

Comment: @Jon, It's true so long as the time element of the date column and the date element of the time column are both zero.

Comment: it does this due to the way the date is stored as a float, with the left part being the date and the right of the decimal being the time, so its like doing 1.0 + 0.5 = 1.5

Comment: I do this and my date is off (early) by 2 days, but the time is correct?

Comment: You are most likely experiencing what is desribed here http://groups.google.be/group/borland.public.delphi.database.sqlservers/browse_frm/thread/b2e07edb46f63cba/1ab62659d8be3135?lnk=st&q=2+sqlserver+com+datetime+group%3A*borland*+author%3A*teamb*#1ab62659d8be3135

Comment: This isn't working for me, using SQL Server 2008 r2, with my Date column as a `date` type, and my Time column as a `time(7)` type

Comment: @STW - Date and Time are types introduced in SQL Server 2008. If you insist on adding, you can use `Combined = CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME)`

Comment: Casting to DATETIME won't work if your date column is earlier than 1/1/1753, and you can't use the add operator with the DATETIME2 type. If you need to support dates that far back, you'll need to use a combination of DateAdd and DateDiff: `Combined = DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, '00:00', MyTime), Convert(datetime2, MyDate))`

Comment: While the addition of datetime/time worked without CAST in SQL 2008/2008R2, it no longer works in SQL 2012, it will produce an error:

"The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator"

Comment: The "zero" date in SQL Server is `1900-01-01`, no?

Comment: When i tried this I did not need to cast the 'time' value to datetime. In other words you can do: datetime + time

Comment: @dnolan dates in SQL server are NOT stored as `float`. Where on earth did you learn this? They are stored as *integers*: the date portion is the number of days since an anchor date, and the time portion is the number of "ticks" since midnight, ticks being defined as 1/300 s for `datetime` and more precise for `time` and `datetime2`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Please see my above comment. Please fix your answer.

Comment: @ErikE - I loved the simplicity of dnolan's comment explaining what was happening but you are right, it's not a float. I have tried to ammend the answer without losing *(too much)* of this simplicity. Feel free to edit the answer further if you feel it's still inadequate and thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I was going to fix your post, but there are more problems. The zero date in SQL Server is not `1899-12-30` but `1900-01-01`, two days later. So your post is factually incorrect for SQL Server: the OP's comment about 2 days off was spot on and the commented answer incorrect: He needs to add two days to account for the 2-day difference between anchor dates. Try it: `select convert(datetime, '2009-03-12 00:00:00.000') + convert(datetime, '1899-12-30 12:30:00.000')`.

Comment: @ErikE - Correct, the [base date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.90).aspx) is indeed 1900-01-01. It amazes me that no-one noticed earlier. Most likely because it is a working solution but with an wrong explanation.

Comment: @ErikE - That does bring up the question as to why OP is showing `1899-12-30` for the time only columns.

Comment: They probably came from another DBMS, perhaps MS Access. Or from Excel. Those two have an anchor date a day or two earlier. Or the DBMS in your link above.

Comment: @ErikE - actually, Andriy already corrected me about the base date to wich I replied but the penny didn't drop for me then that I should alter the answer. I don't know what I was drinking back then but it must have been something strong :)

Comment: Your SQL Server 2008 version loses precision for `time(3) - time(7)`

Comment: @MartinSmith - I haven't tested it but wouldn't `CAST AS DATETIME2(7)` resolve that?

Comment: No. `+` isn't implemented for adding any of the new datatypes. [One method is here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server/51443#51443)

Comment: I can't go blindly copying your answer to this one but I'll edit the answer and refer to yours for SQL Server 2008 and up.

Comment: It was @ypercube's answer in fact! This answer is high in the search results for "combine date and time sql server" so probably quite a few people using the newer datatypes will be coming across it.

Comment: @ErikE: It is correct, it is mostly coming from Excel. I got into same issue in while importing a excel file. Seems like excel [doesn't likes 1/1/1900](http://bit.ly/1EiG2HJ).  So if there is a time column in excel and you are importing and using OLEDB you will get 1899/12/30. While the date (the invoice date, transaction date or whatever) could be in a different column entirely.

Comment: @Liam: is there a way to accomplish this same thing in mysql?

Answer (score 143):

If the time element of your date column *and* the date element of your time column are both zero then [Lieven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700649/370103) is what you need. If you can't guarantee that will always be the case then it becomes slightly more complicated:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, your_date_column)) +
    DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, your_time_column), your_time_column)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luke. Luckily, in this case I can guarantee other items are always zero, I think the 2 fields may even be 1 on the other side the 3rd party code which does the extract for us.

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP except I know the unneeded parts are never zero. This has therefore been immeasurably useful, if I could vote you up twice I would!

Comment: This saved me! I was converting both to chars and then concating and then back to DATETIME, but then I couldn't index it, because SQL said it was non-deterministic. This apparently IS deterministic!!! THANK !!! YOU !!!

Comment: Your SQL Server 2008 version doesn't work. `The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: @Martin: I've removed the broken SQL2008 version.

Comment: Great solution for MS Dynamics NAV default "zero" date of '1754-01-01'. Exactly what I needed. Great Job LukeH

Comment: I would also suggest including an `ISNULL([expr],0)` expression **in case you encounter a null value** in either the date or time. (Otherwise your combined DATETIME will be null.)

Comment: My columns 'your_date_column' and 'your_time_column' were datetime2, so I casted the two addends to datetime to make it work:
    `SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, your_date_column)) AS DATETIME) +
    CAST(DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, your_time_column), your_time_column) AS DATETIME)
    FROM your_table`

Answer (score 32):

This is an alternative solution without any char conversions:

```
DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', [Time]), CONVERT(DATETIME, [Date]))
```

You will only get milliseconds accuracy this way, but that would normally be OK. I have tested this in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Has a rounding up issue? Try `select DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms,'00:00:00','23:59:59.999'), '2023-01-01' )` and it rounds to 2023-01-02 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me

```
CAST(Tbl.date as DATETIME) + CAST(Tbl.TimeFrom AS TIME)
```

(on SQL 2008 R2)

Comment: Worked great in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I get The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator. error on SQL Server 2012

Comment: SQL 2012 
The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator

Comment: This no longer works in SQL Server 2012 and above (breaking change). See here for details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/8c163ac8-dae7-4d95-ad8f-3e4b52c3965d/difference-in-datetime-and-time-arithmetic-in-sql-azure-vs-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: It doesn't work on SQL Server 2019 (15) either.

Comment: Works great for me. For me I didn't need to Cast my date as DateTime because it already was a Datetime. I think your way is more reliable than the other method of [Date] + [TIME] + 2. That other way depends on the Time column always having a year/MM/dd of 1899-12-30 which might not always be the case if the data was imported from another SQLServer or another database which it defaults  the date to 1900-01-01 as the first year/month/day it can support. I am using SQL Server 2014 for this. But I also use SQL Server 2019 and it should work for that too.

Answer (score 10):

If you're not using SQL Server 2008 (i.e. you only have a DateTime data type), you can use the following (admittedly rough and ready) TSQL to achieve what you want:

```
DECLARE @DateOnly AS datetime
DECLARE @TimeOnly AS datetime 

SET @DateOnly = '07 aug 2009 00:00:00'
SET @TimeOnly = '01 jan 1899 10:11:23'


-- Gives Date Only.
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DateOnly))

-- Gives Time Only.
SELECT DATEADD(Day, -DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @TimeOnly), @TimeOnly)

-- Concatenates Date and Time parts.
SELECT
CAST(
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DateOnly)) + ' ' +
    DATEADD(Day, -DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @TimeOnly), @TimeOnly)           
as datetime)
```

It's rough and ready, but it works!

Answer (score 9):

1. If both of your fields are datetime then simply adding those will work.

   eg:

   ```
   Declare @d datetime, @t datetime
   set @d = '2009-03-12 00:00:00.000';
   set @t = '1899-12-30 12:30:00.000';
   select @d + @t
   ```
2. If you used Date & Time datatype then just cast the time to datetime

   eg:

   ```
   Declare @d date, @t time
   set @d = '2009-03-12';
   set @t = '12:30:00.000';
   select @d + cast(@t as datetime)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

This was my solution which ignores the date value of the time column

```sql
CAST(Tbl.date as DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(Tbl.TimeFrom AS TIME) as DATETIME)
```

Hope this helps others

Answer (score 4):

Convert both field into DATETIME :

```
SELECT CAST(@DateField as DATETIME) + CAST(@TimeField AS DATETIME)
```

and if you're using [`Getdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) use this first:

```
DECLARE @FechaActual DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
SELECT CAST(@FechaActual as DATETIME) + CAST(@HoraInicioTurno AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the first date stored in a datetime field to a string, then convert the time stored in a datetime field to string, append the two and convert back to a datetime field all using known conversion formats.

```
Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), MYDATETIMEFIELD, 103) + ' ' + Convert(char(8), MYTIMEFIELD, 108), 103)
```

Comment: Converting to string is slower than dateadd. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Dates table ([Date] datetime);
DECLARE @Times table ([Time] datetime);

INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES('2009-03-12 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES('2009-03-26 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES('2009-03-30 00:00:00.000');

INSERT INTO @Times VALUES('1899-12-30 12:30:00.000');
INSERT INTO @Times VALUES('1899-12-30 10:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @Times VALUES('1899-12-30 10:00:00.000');

WITH Dates (ID, [Date])
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]), [Date] FROM @Dates
), Times (ID, [Time])
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time]), [Time] FROM @Times
)
SELECT Dates.[Date] + Times.[Time] FROM Dates
    JOIN Times ON Times.ID = Dates.ID
```

Prints:

```
2009-03-12 10:00:00.000
2009-03-26 10:00:00.000
2009-03-30 12:30:00.000
```

Answer (score 2):

I had many errors as stated above so I did it like this

```
try_parse(concat(convert(date,Arrival_date),' ',arrival_time) as datetime) AS ArrivalDateTime
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Finding this works for two dates where you want time from one and date from the other:

```
declare @Time as datetime = '2021-11-19 12:34'
declare @Date as datetime = '2021-10-10'
SELECT @time + datediff(day, @Time, @Date)
```

Comment: Beautifully concise

Answer (score 1):

To combine date from a datetime column and time from another datetime column this is the best fastest solution for you:

```
select cast(cast(DateColumn as date) as datetime) + cast(TimeColumn as datetime) from YourTable
```

Comment: Results in error "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: The parameters are datetime

Comment: Blast from the past, haha, I see you edited to fix it some time after I commented, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CAST(CAST(@DateField As Date) As DateTime)  + CAST(CAST(@TimeField As Time) As DateTime)

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.SalesID from SalesTbl s 
        where cast(cast(s.SaleDate  as date) as datetime) + cast(cast(s.SaleCreatedDate as time) as datetime) between @FromDate and @ToDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `CONCAT`and `CAST`, be aware, that you need to use `DATETIME2(x)` to make it work. You can set `x` to anything between `0-7` `7` meaning no precision loss.

```
DECLARE @date date = '2018-03-12'
DECLARE @time time = '07:00:00.0000000'
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(@date, ' ', @time) AS DATETIME2(7))
```

Returns `2018-03-12 07:00:00.0000000`

*Tested on SQL Server 14*

Answer (score 0):

simply concatenate both , but cast them first as below

```
select cast(concat(Cast(DateField as varchar), ' ', Cast(TimeField as varchar)) as datetime) as DateWithTime from TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers do not address the `datetime2` datatype so I will add mine:

Assuming that you want to add a [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) value to a [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) value where:

- The `datetime2` value could contain non-zero time component and/or fractional seconds
- The `time` value could contain the value `23:59:59.9999999` which is 86,399.9999999 seconds, 86,399,999,999.9 microseconds or 86,399,999,999,900 nanoseconds¹

Due to the limitations of [`dateadd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function¹ you must add them in two steps:

- Convert the time value to seconds and use `dateadd(second, ...)`
- Extract the nanoseconds from the time value and use `dateadd(nanosecond, ...)` to add them to the date calculated above

```
declare @dv datetime2 = '2000-01-01 12:34:56.7890123';
declare @tv time = '23:59:59.9999999';
select dateadd(
    nanosecond,
    datepart(nanosecond, @tv),
    dateadd(
        second,
        datepart(hour, @tv) * 60 * 60 + datepart(minute, @tv) * 60 + datepart(second, @tv),
        @dv
    )
);
-- 2000-01-02 12:34:56.7890122
```

---

¹ Nanosecond values might not fit in [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) datatype which `dateadd` function expects.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CAST(your_date_column AS date) + CAST(your_time_column AS datetime) FROM your_table
```

Works like a charm

Comment: Results in error "The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator." SQL Server 2019 (version 15)

Answer (score -2):

I ran into similar situation where I had to merge Date and Time fields to DateTime field. None of the above mentioned solution work, specially adding two fields as the data type for addition of these 2 fields is not same.

I created below solution, where I added hour and then minute part to the date. This worked beautifully for me. Please check it out and do let me know if you get into any issues.

;with tbl
as
(
    select StatusTime = '12/30/1899 5:17:00 PM', StatusDate = '7/24/2019 12:00:00 AM'
)
select DATEADD(MI, DATEPART(MINUTE,CAST(tbl.StatusTime AS TIME)),DATEADD(HH, DATEPART(HOUR,CAST(tbl.StatusTime AS TIME)), CAST(tbl.StatusDate as DATETIME)))
from tbl

Result: 2019-07-24 17:17:00.000