# How to combine two columns together to create a new column in a select statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql

Hope you can help. I have a Date column and a time column and i want to be able to combine these together within a select statement so there is just one column for [Date and Time]. Everything ive tried seem to add them together instead of combining/appending.

Cheers, :)

Comment: What you mean by add them together?

Comment: No just taking what is in DateColumn and TimeColumn & then showing them together in another column so it would be Date&TimeColumn

Comment: @sllev, adding them together mathematically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Its come to light now that once the new [Date&Time] column has been created it will be included in a where clause to see if it is greater than another [Date&Time] column. also it is SQL server 2005

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2008 R2 you can use this(not in 2005):

```
DECLARE @TESTTBL TABLE ( dt DATE, tm TIME)
INSERT INTO @TESTTBL VALUES('2011-02-03', '01:02:03')
INSERT INTO @TESTTBL VALUES('2011-02-04', '02:03:04')

SELECT CAST(dt AS DATETIME) + CAST(tm AS DATETIME) FROM @TESTTBL
```

Result will be:

2011-02-03 01:02:03.000

2011-02-04 02:03:04.000

If you want the text's together, use varchar instead of datetime in the cast().

Comment: Yes, date & time is only in 2008. In 2005, it would most likely use two datetimes instead, and the right solution for the varchar version would be something like: SELECT LEFT(CONVERT ( varchar , dt ,21 ), 11) + RIGHT(CONVERT ( varchar , tm ,21 ), 9) FROM @TESTTBL

Comment: This will work as well 'SELECT dt + CAST(tm AS DATETIME) FROM @TESTTBL'

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Its come to light now that once the new [Date&Time] column has been created it will be included in a where clause to see if it is greater than another [Date&Time] column. also it is SQL server 2005

Comment: @ODDBEAR just tried your solution and it seems to work, thanks alot!!