# Sql Convert Text Field To Date Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm importing an access database to sql.

The original access database has a date field that imports nicely, but the time field is text (10:00 AM, for instance).

I have over 4000 records and assume there is a way to convert 10:00 AM to 10:00:00.000 (or 07:30 PM to 19:30:00.000, etc...) so that it can be combined with the pre-existing date field (which is now like 2011-11-11 00:00:00.000).

Also, if it's easy to do the conversion and concatenation in the same process, please note.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: I was looking at that as the second step in the process.  I was wanting to get the date in the appropriate format so I could use that information to combine the two fields.

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert the time from am or pm `10:00 PM` format  into time format `10:00:00.000`:

```
select cast(timestring as time(7))
```

Comment: Ok...

SELECT cast([time] as time(7)) FROM [Sermons].[dbo].[TblSermon]

did show the time in the appropriate fashion.  But that is just a query, would I need to do an update query to actually change those values in the table?

Comment: @doubleJ, you can update the two string date and time columns into one datetime column like that `update tablename set datetimecolumn = convert(datetime,datestring + ' ' + CAST(CONVERT(time, timestring ,121) AS VARCHAR(20)),121) 
`

Comment: Hehehe...That worked perfectly, except for the records that I manually set the time portion of the date field.  It looks like it added the time field to the pre-existing data.

Comment: Actually, it was worse.  It change the date to the next day if it passed 24 hours.  Hehehe...Live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

look this:

```
declare @timeField as varchar(10)
set @timeField = '07:30 PM'

declare @dateField as varchar(10)
set @dateField = '1900-01-01'

select CONVERT(datetime,@dateField + ' ' + CAST(CONVERT(time, @timeField ,121) AS VARCHAR(11)),121)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

In your import scripts (I assume you use some sort of SQL to E.T.L your data from Access to SQL server), you can use the convert function as such:

```
declare @t as time = Convert(time, '10:00PM' )
print @t -- prints 22:00:00.0000000
```

OR

```
declare @t as time = Convert(time, '10:00AM' )
print @t -- prints 10:00:00.0000000
```

And of course if you want to control the precision as per your example:

```
Convert(time(3), '10:00PM' ) -- prints 22:00:00.000
```

Comment: He doesn't say which version of sql, so time may not be supported.

Comment: Apologies...It's Ms Sql 2008 R2

Comment: No worries, then you should have no problem with the proposed solution.

Comment: Edit AM to PM in Convert(time(3), '10:00AM' ) -- prints 22:00:00.000 :)

Comment: I didn't manually create a script, if one was used.  I exported a query from access 2010 into an access 2003 database, transferred that database to the sql server, right-clicked on the appropriate database, and chose Tasks - Import Data (selecting access, the file, etc...).

Comment: Then you need to write a simple script that runs, post-import process to reformat the columns as desired. I assume there is no impediment to prevent this. If so, please give me details.