# Combine Date from one field with time from another field - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How can I in SSIS combine these two fields into 1 column of type datetime? Both source tables are in datetime and so is the target table.

```
Dates
2009-03-12 00:00:00.000 
2009-03-26 00:00:00.000 
2009-03-26 00:00:00.000 

 Times
1899-12-30 12:30:00.000 
1899-12-30 10:00:00.000 
1899-12-30 10:00:00.000
```

Comment: check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two steps to achieve your goal.

1) First merge both Dates and Times into a single row.  I am guessing you have a key to tie the two up, so use this inside a merge join transformation (you will need to sort by this column prior to entering the merge) to create a single row e.g.

[image: Merge Join Transformation]

2) Convert the two columns into one inside a derived column transformation with the following casts `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,23)Dates,1,11) + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,23)Times,12,8))`

This should provide you with a new column of datetime to insert into your database e.g.

[image: Merge Join Example]

Comment: Hi Daryl! Wow, this is a very thorough explaination.  You are a star! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A tidier and more efficient way to do calculate the derived column where you add the time to the date is to use the following expression:

```
DATEADD("Ms",DATEDIFF("Ms",NULL(DT_DATE),[Time]),[Date])
```

This works in 2 parts: on the inside, the `DATEDIFF("Ms",NULL(DT_DATE),[Time])` calculates how many milliseconds the `[Time]` is past above the `null` date (i.e. `1899-12-30 00:00:00` in this case), and then the outer part of the expression adds that number of milliseconds to the `[Date]`, e.g. if the time is 01:00:00, that's 3,600,000 milliseconds, so it ends up adding `DATEADD("Ms",3600000,[Date])`, or adding an hour to the date.