# Performing date/time subtraction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have four columns in a table:

```
date entered, time entered, date completed, time completed
```

I would like to know the difference between date/time ENTERED and date/time COMPLETED

For example

```
date entered = 1/1/2001
time entered = 10:00
time completed = 1/2/2001
time completed = 11:00
```

The difference is 25 hours.

How can I perform this computation with a select statement?

I tried this:

```
DATEDIFF(hh,dateadd(hh,[Time Entered],[Date Entered]),dateadd(hh,[Time Completed],[Date Completed]) ) AS [Hours]
```

and got the following error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Argument data type time is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: This topic is covered here, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Declare @dateentered date = '20010101'
Declare @timeentered time = '10:00' 
Declare @datecompleted date = '20010102' 
Declare @timecompleted time = '11:00'

select datediff(hh, @dateentered + cast(@timeentered as datetime), 
                    @datecompleted + cast(@timecompleted as datetime))
```

So, in terms of your tables' columns:

```
select datediff(hh, [date entered] + cast([time entered] as datetime), 
                    [date completed] + cast([time completed] as datetime)) as [Hours]
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, although I would have casted the "date" field to a datetime instead of the "time".

Comment: You have to be REALLY careful here.  It looks like things are working fine but that's only because of the low resolution times that you're using.  You can get rounding even into the next year if you're not careful.  Please see the following article for more on the subject including two correct methods for combining DATE and TIME columns.  

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

```
select datediff(hour,'1/1/2001 10:00','1/2/2001 11:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) sql function.

Comment: thank you! i just updated my question can you take a look please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select DateDiff(ss, [Date Entered] + convert(datetime, [Time Entered]), 
                    [Date Completed] + convert(datetime, [Time Completed])) 
from myTable
```

to get the result in seconds.

Here's a standalone example:

```
declare @dateentered date = '1/1/2001'
declare @timeentered time = '10:00'
declare @datecompleted date = '1/2/2001'
declare @timecompleted time = '11:00'

select DateDiff(ss, 
    @dateentered + convert(datetime, @timeentered), 
    @datecompleted + convert(datetime, @timecompleted))
```

And of course you can specify different *dateparts* as specified for [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql).

Comment: updated my answer to one that works (if your columns are date or datetime)

Comment: Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.

Comment: Fixed since you're using date and time types.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
Declare @EndDate DATETIME
declare @startime datetime
declare @endime datetime

SET @StartDate = '2001-01-01'
set @startime = '10:00'
SET @EndDate = '2001-01-02'
set @endime = '11:00'

set @StartDate = @StartDate + @startime
set @EndDate = @EndDate + @endime

--To get only Hours
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, @StartDate,@EndDate ) AS [Hours];
```