# Concatenate Date and Time Variable using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have two Columns in my SQL Table. One is DateTime and The other is Time
They are in the Format,
`DateTime - 2012-04-05 16:58:56.000` and Time - `21:30:00.00000`

I need to write a Query which will return a Column as - `2012-04-05 21:30:00.000`

Can you Help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>In SQL-Server 2008, you can add the values this way:</strike>

```
select cast(dt as date) + cast(tm as datetime)
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65645/3)

The above no longer works, here is an updated version that will work in SQL Server. This can also be [edited to include additional precision](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51443/9003):

```
SELECT dateadd(day, datediff(day,'19000101',dt), CAST(tm AS DATETIME))
from yourtable
```

[See Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/516769).

Comment: This did not work from in 2012 and this actually changed the date to some new date

Comment: @hsanivag Considering this was tagged with SQL Server 2008 the answer was specific to that version.  The SQL Fiddle link confirmed that it did work for that version.

Comment: Please check the explanation here, this the code is working fine but for specific scenario  and the links below will give you better explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/700647/2634848

Comment: @hsanivag I've updated the answer with a version that should work in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked For Me.

```
Select DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d, 0, Cast(OrderDate As datetime)), Cast(Delivery_Time as datetime))   From myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(date_col AS DATETIME)+CAST(time_col AS DATETIME) FROM your_table
```

Tested on SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: Works fine but for specific scenario. Please check the below link for additional explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/700647/2634848

Answer (score -1):

Try this::

```
Select CONCAT(DATE(column_dateTIME),column_Time) from my Table
```

Comment: It Returns `'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: @SashiKant The question is about sql-server, I have retagged it as such already. How is your sql-server kung fu Sashi?

Answer (score -1):

For MySQL

```
Select CONCAT_WS(" ", date(dattime_columnname), time(time_column)) from table_name;
```

For SQL Server 2008:

```
select convert(varchar, datetime_column, 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar, time_column, 114)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

This should work in SQL SERVER

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10),dt_col,121)+' '+cast(t_col as varchar(20)) 
from your_table
```