# How to add date and time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two variables `@date` of type `datetime` and `@time` of type `time`. I want to add both to get another `datetime` variable. And I want to perform further calculations on it.

Ex:

```
Declare @date datetime
Declare @time time
```

I want something like this

```
@date = @date + @time (but not concatenation)

SELECT @Startdate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date )
```

Is there any way?

Comment: You're just missing "set" in front of @date?

Comment: not even after doing set @date it is just concatenating both fields. i will not be perform  dateadd operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining (concatenating) date and time into a datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622384/combining-concatenating-date-and-time-into-a-datetime)

Comment: I think you are forgeting to and SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tranform your time to seconds and add them to your datetime value:

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = GETDATE(),
        @time TIME = '01:16:24',
        @timeinseconds INT

PRINT 'we add ' + CAST(@time AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@datetime,120)+ ':'


SELECT @timeinseconds = DATEPART(SECOND, @time)
                        + DATEPART(MINUTE, @time) * 60
                        + DATEPART(HOUR, @time) * 3600

SET @datetime = DATEADD(SECOND,@timeinseconds,@datetime)

PRINT 'The result is: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@datetime,120)
```

Output:

```
we add 01:16:24 to 2015-07-17 09:58:45:
The result is: 2015-07-17 11:15:09
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you are missing is that @time needs to be cast back to a datetime before adding to @date.

```
declare @date datetime = '2022-05-26'
declare @time time = '09:52:14'
declare @Startdate datetime

set @date = @date + convert(datetime,@time)

SELECT @Startdate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date)
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: It seems that in modern versions of SqlServer it's now impossible to add DateTime and Time, we always get the "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator" Error.

 @bryan-Williams solution's should now  be the accepted solution to add DateTime and Time variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take only date part from `@date` and time part from `@time` -  can convert your `@date` and `@time` to strings, concatenate the values and convert back to datetime:

```
select cast(convert(nvarchar(20), @date, 104) + ' ' +
            convert(nvarchar(20), @time, 108) as datetime2)
```

Or, alternatively, if you need to add time to datetime value, you can do something like:

```
select dateadd(ms, 
           datepart(ms, @time), 
           dateadd(ss, 
                   datepart(ss, @time), 
                   dateadd(mi, 
                           datepart(mi, @time), 
                           dateadd(hh, datepart(hh, @time), @date))))
```

Comment: i tried this. but its not working. its not doing the it. but its not performing         SELECT @Startdate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@date )

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert `@date` and `@time` variables to `NVARCHAR()`, then concat them and after It convert It to `DATETIME` datatype. After It you can use `DATEADD` function on It. Try in following:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME 
DECLARE @time TIME

SET @date = GETDATE()
SET @time = '10:12:13'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @date, 110) + ' ' +
                             CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @time, 108) AS DATETIME))
```

**OUTPUT** (*Today day -1 + time '10:12:13'*):

```
2015-07-16 10:12:13.000
```

Comment: What should this be doing? Can you explain your idea behind this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what's going on here, but if your variables are datetime and time types, this should work just fine:

```
declare @date datetime
declare @time time

set @date = '20150717'
set @time = '12:34:56'

set @date = @date + @time

select @date, DATEADD(DAY,-1,@date)
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1978)

If the problem is that @date contains also time part, you can use:

```
set @date = convert(datetime, convert(date, @date)) + @time
```

Comment: Error:  "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: @BryanWilliams I'm guessing something has changed over the years, at least based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514726/the-data-types-date-and-datetime-are-incompatible-in-the-add-operator

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '1/1/2020'
DECLARE @time TIME = '1:00 pm'
DECLARE @Startdate DATETIME

SET @date = @date + @time

SELECT @Startdate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date)

@date = 2020-01-01 13:00:00.000
@Startdate = 2019-12-31 13:00:00.000
```

It isn't concatenating, it is adding them together. The time on @date is 0:00:00.000, so it might appear to be concatenating them. But change @date to '1/1/2020 1:00 am' and then:

```
@date = 2020-01-01 14:00:00.000
@Startdate = 2019-12-31 14:00:00.000
```

Comment: Doesn't work:  "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't work for you. I just copied and pasted it into SSMS, and it still works exactly as I have it above. At the time I was using SSMS v17, now I am using v18. But it shouldn't make a difference, as you can always add TIME to a DATETIME variable. So I'm not sure it deserved a down vote.

Comment: Doesn't work for me also : "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator". I'm using SSMS v18 with a SqlServer 2019 instance

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2016. According to the following comment, newer versions can't handle this code?  If not, that potentially breaks a lot of people's code when they upgrade. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470858/how-to-add-date-and-time-in-sql-server/63800428?noredirect=1#comment130166900_72477762