# The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server, datetime, types, sqldatatypes, sql-server-2016

I recently created in a SQL Server 2008 dev environment a function that concatenates a date and time like this

```
select cast('2016-11-09 15:35:00' AS DATE) + CAST('00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

In SQL Server 2008 it works well but deployed in SQL Server 2016 it throws an error

> The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.

But it works well ONLY if queries are placed separately

```
select cast('2016-11-09 15:35:00' AS DATE)
select CAST('00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

So, how can I fix this. I found articles where people say that there is an incompatibility with `TIME` data type, but I am not using it. In fact, my concatenation is like this

```
 WHERE 
     CREATIONDATE BETWEEN CAST(@CurrentDate AS DATE) + CAST('00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@CurrentDate AS DATE) + CAST('23:59:59' AS DATETIME)
```

where `@CurrentDate` is a `DateTime` variable and passed to my function as '2016-11-09 15:35:00'

I cannot modify the configuration of the SQL Server 2016 box. How can I fix my code?

Thanks

Comment: Just cast it as a date and then a datetime. `select cast(cast('2016-11-09 15:35:00' as date) as datetime)` and then use dateadd `select dateadd(dd,1,cast(cast('2016-11-09 15:35:00' as date) as datetime))`. I'm not a huge fan of the between operator so when i deal with datetimes i tend to use > startDate and < endDate where the endDate is the next day , so 11/10 which is like saying <= 11/09 23:59:59

Comment: Thank you. You saved the day. Post it as an answer please.

Comment: Glad to help Maximus

Comment: I don't get this question, you're comparing apples and oranges. The first SQL is wrong because of the `+`. In the second SQL, you're not adding them together, whatever problem there was with the `+` is obviously not even present in this SQL. What is your question here? Basically SQL Server is telling you that you cannot add (`+`) a DATE and a DATETIME. "So how I can fix this"? Fix what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast it as a date and then a datetime.

`select cast(cast('2016-11-09 15:35:00' as date) as datetime)`

To get 1 more day, use:

`dateadd select dateadd(dd,1,cast(cast('2016-11-09 15:35:00' as date) as datetime))`

I'm not a huge fan of the between operator so when i deal with datetimes i tend to use > startDate and < endDate where the endDate is the next day , so 11/10 which is like saying <= 11/09 23:59:59