# Execute/Create script function with errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there a way in Sql Server 2016 to create a script function even with errors?

I have a Sql Server 2008 script that I know is incompatible with Sql Server 2016 and the server is preventing me to create this script.

Is there a command on the query window to disable errors checking temporarily?

```
--SET ERROR CHECKING TO OFF
CREATE FUNCTION (Parameters)
BEGIN
END
GO
--SET THE ERROR CHECKING AGAIN TO ON
```

**UDPATE**

I solved this altering the compatibility level to 2008 then I executed the query and finally I set the compatibility level to 2016 again.

Comment: I don't understand - why would you want to?

Comment: Because of an emergency I modified production environment but I need to revert to the previous conflicted script. I have 2 query window tabs. One with the modified version and one with the original code. I tested the modified version, now I want to ALTER the function to its original version but it doesn't allow me. It is a DATETIME concatenation that we are gonna solve later. So I want to ignore the error checking of SQL Server to allow me alter my function and then reenable it.

Comment: I doubt you can do that, especially if you are asking it to ignore a pretty huge requirement concerning data types.

Comment: @dfundako I got a workaround. Updated in my question.

Comment: Other than a removed datatype (which I don't think there were any) what could you write in 2008 that is not valid in 2016?

Comment: It was a concatenation "+" between date and time data types. I needed to cast as datetime.

Comment: I truly am curious. Could you post the code that didn't work? I can't think of how you would be able to do this in 2008 but not 2016.

Comment: This was my previous question. I had a function that didn't run in 2016 but in 2008 was ok. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514726/the-data-types-date-and-datetime-are-incompatible-in-the-add-operator