# Check if current time is between two different times in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, time, datetimeoffset, datepart

I want to check if the current time is between 10 PM and [4 AM (the next day)] in SQL.

```
DECLARE @tt TIME
SET @tt = CONVERT(TIME, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

-- `2023-09-12 19:19:35.4692966 -05:00`

This will get me the current time, but how can I check if it is between 10 PM today and 4 AM the next day?

Comment: get today's date, contact with 10pm, convert to date, same for tomorrow's date + 4am then use `@tt between tds and tmw` here the how to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18622384/460557

Comment: HOUR(@tt) not between 4 and 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the current time is between 10 PM and 4 AM (the next day) in SQL Server, you can use the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @CurrentTime TIME = GETDATE();  -- Get the current time

IF @CurrentTime >= '22:00:00' OR @CurrentTime < '04:00:00'
BEGIN
    -- Current time is between 10 PM and 4 AM (the next day)
    PRINT 'Current time is within the specified range.'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Current time is not within the specified range
    PRINT 'Current time is outside the specified range.'
END
```