# Adding time values in a loop

Tags: sql, function, time

am trying to create sql userdefined functionwhen am trying to add two time values ex 09:00:00+18:00:00
shows error value here i get ans like 03:00:00

my code is

```
declare @StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime,@hoursInAWorkday time
set @StartDate='10/07/2013 08:00:00'
set @EndDate='10/10/2013 17:00:00'
declare @time1 time = '00:00:00';
declare @time2 time = '09:00:00';

while @StartDate<@EndDate
Begin
set @StartDate=DATEADD(D,1,@StartDate)
set @time2= DATEADD(hh,9,@time1)
set @time1=@time2
End
```

here 9+9 i got 18 but after that i am getting wrong answers.plz plz help me....

Comment: This post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Your code does **not** produce an error and getting 03:00:00 is correct because you are adding 9 hours every loop

Comment: For example 6pm + 9 hours is 3am

Comment: ok..plz help me how to convert date time to varchar..i need to set a datetime to variable of type varchar

Comment: `code` 
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate='10/07/2013 08:00:00'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @StartDate)
`code` 

This will give you "Oct  7 2013  8:00AM"