# Convert datetime and varchar to single date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a following database columns and the values

`MyDate datetime` and `My_Time  varchar(5)`

the values stored are

`2006-09-05 00:00:00.000` and `16:47`

Now I want to add this two columns and get a single `datetime` value `2006-09-05 16:47:00.000`

How can I do this in SQL ?

***UPDATE:***

Some rows have `NULL` values for DocDate and DocTime.

So i am getting error like `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: Disagree with duplicate since as shown below, there is a cleaner answer for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select dateadd(ss, datediff(ss, 0, @My_Time), @MyDate)
```

Key point is to understand that it's the same as...

```
select dateadd(ss, datediff(ss, 0, cast(@My_Time as time)), @MyDate)
```

...but the conversion is done explicitly.

**EDIT**

For default time and/or date, use ISNULL or COALESCE as appropriate.

Example:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(
      isnull(@date, '2000-1-1') + 
      isnull(@time, '0:0') 
    AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: What is `ss`? can you provide some link for this?

Comment: ss = seconds = expression uses seconds for calculation

Comment: You have to be clear what do you want if data is missing. If you want to throw the error, you have it. If you want to substitute NULL time for midnight, or substitute NULL date for certain year, use ISNULL or COALESCE.

Answer (score 1):

Simply...

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(5)

SET @date = '2006-09-05 00:00:00.000'
SET @time = '16:47'

SELECT CAST(@date + @time AS DATETIME) -- 2006-09-05 16:47:00.000
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, this is a better solution than mine :P

Comment: Sometimes I may have `NULL` values for MyDate and MyTime. So i am getting error like `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME) as CombinedDate
```