# SQL Query Starting time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time

trying to find a query to select data that will start at specific time 08:00 till the next day at 08:00, i have separate date and time fields and also selecting specific criteria from date to date.

```
select * from table 
where datefield between '2014-01-14' and '2014-01-14' 
      and timefield between '08:00' and '08:00'
```

Comment: You are selecting records from the same day and time.  What RDMS are you using? If you're using SQL Server you can use `DATEADD`.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation, we are using MS SQl Server, DATEADD as i understand is for datetime fields, we need to add criteria for separate time and date fields

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why `datefield` and `timefield` is not saved in a `datetime`-column.
Also I don't know what `timefield` is, but if `<` and `>` works on the datatype, this will work:

```
select * from table 
where (datefield = '2014-01-14' and timefield >= '08:00')
or (datefield = '2014-01-15' and timefield < '08:00')
```

Edit: Just learned you can just add a `date` and `time` field together to a `datetime`

```
select * from table 
where (datefield + timefield) >= '2014-01-11 08:00'
and (datefield + timefield) < '2014-01-13 08:00'
```

[Here's the source of adding them together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: Great but it doesn't work if we select other dates                select * from table 
where (datefield = '2014-01-11' and timefield >= '08:00')
or (datefield = '2014-01-13' and timefield < '08:00')

Comment: Problem is that you are killing the performance when comparing fields like that (second solution). Which is why I went out of my way to avoid that solution

Comment: Oh and furthermore you can't add a date and a time. You can however add a datetime and a time.

Comment: Oh, ok. So might have to `convert(datetime,datefield) + timefield`. I agree with the performance issue. Thats's why I would prefer to save it as `datetime` in one column from the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @from datetime = '2014-01-14 08:00'
declare @to   datetime = '2014-01-15 08:00'
select * from table
where datefield between cast(@from as date) and @to
and not(datefield = cast(@from as date) and timefield < cast(@from as time))
and not(datefield = cast(@to as date) and timefield > cast(@to as time))
```