# Concatenating Date and Time from two different columns to a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date column with datatype as `Date` and a time column with datatype as `Time`.

```
Column A    Column B
4/6/2015    13:25:18
4/10/2015   12:52:14
4/10/2015   10:39:48
```

I need to join these two columns and insert into a column with datatype `Datetime`.

```
Column C
2015-06-04 13:25:18
2015-10-4 12:52:14
2015-10-4 10:39:48
```

I have only date in one column and only time in another column and i'm using the below now which is throwing an error

```
CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([ColumnA], 12) + LEFT([Column B], 7), 101) as ColumnC
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server

Comment: Column A  Column B
4/6/2015        13:25:18
4/10/2015       12:52:14
4/10/2015 10:39:48
Need to insert into another column as '2015-06-04 13:25:18' ... let me know if you need more details

Comment: Put your comments in the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #test([Column A] DATE, [Column B] TIME, [Column C] DATETIME2)

INSERT INTO #test([Column A], [Column B]) VALUES  ('4/6/2015', '13:25:18')
                                                 ,('4/10/2015', '12:52:14')
                                                 ,('4/10/2015', '10:39:48')

UPDATE #test
SET [Column C] = CAST([Column A] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST([Column B] AS VARCHAR(8))

SELECT * FROM #test
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

**1.** If you are just doing doing a *select query*, this will help:

```
SELECT FORMAT([Column A],'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + FORMAT([Column B],'')AS [Column C] FROM TableName;
```

**2.** But, if you want to *add new column* to *existing* table and add *existing date and time values* of each row in this new column, this will help:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD [Column C] smalldatetime;
UPDATE TableName
SET [Column C] = FORMAT([Column A],'yyyy-MM-dd') + ' ' + CAST([Column B] AS varchar);
```