# Combine datetime from two datetimes - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

How can I combine a datetime value from two datetimes.
The first value contains appropriate date and the second value contains appropriate time (but also has a date that I want to skip).

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2016-12-08 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @time DATETIME = '2016-12-07 12:15:00.000'
```

`SELECT @date + @time` returns: `2133-11-14 12:15:00.000`
but I want: `2016-12-08 12:15:00.000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: LukeH's answer on the referenced post should be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *style* part in `Convert` function to extract `date` and `time` in `varchar`(avoids some explicit conversion to `varchar`) type and concat the the results to get the result date

- 112 to extract date
- 114 to extract time

Try this

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2016-12-08 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @time DATETIME = '2016-12-07 12:15:00.000'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @date, 112) + ' '
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @time, 114))
```

**Result :** `2016-12-08 12:15:00.000`

Comment: Works great, Thanks!