# To fetch records between two dates (today and yesterday) considering day andTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have three columns named docDt , docDateTime and docTime .

Where as docDt contains only date part(eg. 2017-01-01 00:00:00:000) and docTime contains only time(eg. 1900-01-01 22:00:00:000)

Also i am storing combined docDt and docTime to docDateTime (ie. 2017-01-01 22:00:00:000)

I'm inserting new record to table dated docDt(2017-01-02 00:00:00:000) and docTime(1900-01-01 10:00:00:000) and also storing combined date and time(2017-01-02 10:00:00:000) docDateTime .

Now I need to fetch records greater than the mentioned 2017-01-01 22:00:00:000

I have tried using the following condition

```
CONVERT(varchar(8), STH.DocTime , 108) >= '22:00:00.000' and CONVERT(varchar(10),  STH.DocDt , 120) >='2017-01-01' ORDER BY STH.DocDt
```

NOTE: for docTime by default date is 1900-01-01

> EDIT: docDateTime only for reference we can't use that because it will be stored in mysql. where as doctime and docdt are stored in sqlserver

May I get any help.

Comment: you are not highlighting the issue with your try, what are you getting when you compare with docDateTime?

Comment: your docTime column data type might be the Datetime.so when you are trying to insert only time by default it appends date **1900-01-01** to your time.try to change the datatype format as time or else you should insert with date.for your reference check this query.                      `create table #tab (time_date datetime)
insert into #tab values('22:44:36')

create table #tab1 (time_date time)
insert into #tab1 values('22:44:36')

select * from #tab
select * from #tab1`

Comment: @AnilKumar need to get latest records after 2017-01-01 22:00:00:000

Comment: Trying to understand the relevance of docDateTime column mentioned in the question, when we can not use this.

Comment: you can look for approach in so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your time part of the date column `docDt` is always zero and date part of the time column `docTime` is also always base date (1900-01-01), then you can simply add this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  docDt + docTime > '2017-01-01 22:00:00:000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the dates: (It works completely fine):

```
DECLARE @DATE TABLE (docDt  DATETIME,docTime DATETIME,docDateTime DATETIME )
INSERT INTO @DATE VALUES('2017-01-01 00:00:00:000','1900-01-01 22:00:00:000','2017-01-01 22:00:00:000')
INSERT INTO @DATE VALUES('2017-01-02 00:00:00:000','1900-01-01 10:00:00:000','2017-01-02 10:00:00:000')

SELECT * FROM @DATE WHERE docDateTime>'2017-01-01 22:00:00:000'
```

-- or ( as per your requirement)

```
select * from @DATE where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), docDt, 120)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), docTime, 108))>'2017-01-01 22:00:00:000'
```

result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2017-01-02 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 10:00:00.000|2017-01-02 10:00:00.000|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks, i need to fetch date from docDt column and time from docTime., I won't get combined records like this '2017-01-01 22:00:00:000'.

Comment: @user4246662, but you are mentioned , you are storing combined docDt and docTime to docDateTime.

Comment: we have use only docdt and doctime

Answer (score -1):

Try with docDateTime

```
 docDateTime >2017-01-01 22:00:00:000
```

Comment: Thanks, records are stored in different columns