# Combining DATE AND TIME

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, mssql-jdbc

I need to take a DATETIME column (Column A) that contains only a date, then add a VARCHAR(5) column (Column B) which contains a 24-hour representation of a time (i.e. 13:30) and combine them to get a valid DATETIME to be used in a DATEDIFF command.

So for example, Column A contains 2019-06-27 00:00:00.000 and Column B contains 13:30. The result should be 2019-06-27 13:30:00.000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: What's wrong with `YourDatetimeColumn + YourVarcharTimeColumn`?

Answer (score 1):

Cast ColumnA and ColumnB as datetime and concatenate the two columns.

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (ColumnA DATETIME, ColumnB TIME)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES ('2019-06-27 00:00:00.000','13:30')

SELECT
ColumnA,
ColumnB,
cast(ColumnA as datetime)+cast(ColumnB as datetime) AS NewColumn
FROM @TBL
```

Result

```
    ColumnA                    ColumnB                NewColumn
2019-06-27 00:00:00.000    13:30:00.0000000      2019-06-27 13:30:00.000
```