# Concatenate and convert data stored separately as date and time and compare to another piece of data stored similarly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server. I have two columns in a table. The date column stores date as `varchar`. A sample data stored in the date column is `2006-05-29 00:00:00.000`. The time column is also stored as `varchar`. A sample data stored in the time column is `02:00 PM`. I have to concatenate data and time and compare to another date and time in a similar format.

Essentially I have to concatenate `2006-05-29 00:00:00.000` and `02:00 PM` and then concatenate another piece of data `2006-05-29 00:00:00.000` and `08:00 PM` and compare them.

Comment: Wait, what? Why not compare the dates with the dates and the times with the times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine date from one field with time from another field - MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700619/how-to-combine-date-from-one-field-with-time-from-another-field-ms-sql-server)

Comment: *The date column stores date as varchar* - well, that's your main problem right there. After all: you should **always** use the **most appropriate** datatype for everything - and using `varchar` for storing dates and times ***ISN'T*** the most appropriate datatype. Fix that first - before wasting any more time on trying to compare those columns.....

Comment: Sebastian, I already saw that question which you have mentioned as duplicate. However, the format in which time is stored in my case is totally different. Thanks.

Comment: marc_s, it's an existing table and they don't want to change the format now.

Comment: @Massey - But you didn't tried, do you? the solutions working with your values too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing date/time values as strings is not the way to go.  SQL Server (and other databases) have built-in types for date/time values.  Use them!  They are there for a reason.

That said, your strings are readily convertible to date/time values.  And you can add two `datetime`s.  So you can do:

```
select try_convert(datetime, datecol) + convert(datetime, try_convert(time, timecol))
```