# Append time from table to getdate() while using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to append time from a column to a date and use in a case statment

`getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time'`

this is what i've tried so far

```
select case when 
getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time'  <= 
cast(cast (getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time'as date) as datetime) + endtime from tablename where id = 'uniqueid'
1 else 0 end
```

datatype of `endtime` column is nvarchar and the format of the time is `21:00`

and this is the error that i am getting

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'`

I have tried using this solution as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/700647 but still the same error. But when i do

`select CAST(CAST(getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time' AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + endtime from tablename where id = 'uniqueid'`

i get a proper response of `2020-01-07 07:00:00.000`

and this seems to work fine as well

```
select case when
getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time' >= 
CAST(CAST(CAST(getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time'AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + '' + '10:00'as DATETIME)
then 1 else 0
end
```

returns 1

but

```
select case when 
getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time' <=
cast(CAST(CAST(getdate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time' AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + endtime from table where id = 'uniqueid' as datetime) 
then 1 else 0 end
```

returns `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'`

I am not sure if i am doing something wrong or is it a limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue is that you are trying to use a subquery without using a subquery, which is what the syntax error is all about. Try this instead (expanded out for clarity)

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN getdate() at TIME zone 'Central Standard Time' <= 
            (SELECT cast(cast(getdate() at TIME zone 'Central Standard Time' AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + endtime FROM tablename WHERE id = 'uniqueid') -- Subquery
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
```