# remove time from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Please can any ove suggest me how i can remove time part from sql dates. I have already read 100s of articles and most of them remove the time but leaves 00:00:00 behine which i don't want also i know that i can remove these ZERO's by doing a convert to varchar but unfortunately i cannot change the type of the date column it has to be date type instead of string

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: you might want to tag this with the specific database you are using - SQL Server, Oracle, mysql...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A datetime column in the database will *always* contain both a date portion and a time portion. SQL Server 2008 introduces types that store only date or only time. But, so long as the column is of type datetime, you'll have to accept that the time portion exists, and you can just ignore it in your application (by applying suitable formatting).

You can add a check constraint to the table to ensure that all entries in the column always have the same time portion (e.g. 00:00:00).

Answer (score 2):

A SQL server DateTime type is a date and a time in SQL 2005 there is no date only field type, you cannot remove the time component and still have a field that is a DateTime type.  Your options are the ones you have outlined:  Convert to (n)varchar and remove the time componenet, leave it as a DateTime and accept that it has a time component.  Why do you wish to remove the time component, what problem would this solve for you.

Further to your comment below, the database is not where you should be formating you Date strings to display in your GridView.  You do display layer things in the display layer, in this case in the gridview.  You need to use a format string in your data when data binding to the gridview.  Yee examples below.

BoundField:

```
<columns>
  <asp:BoundField headertext="CreationDate" dataformatstring="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" //rearrange these letters as necessary
       datafield="CreationDate"  />
</columns>
```

TemplateField

```
<itemtemplate>
    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreationDate", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
</itemtemplate>
```

Comment: I show this date column in one of my grid view in asp.net and i din't want it to show the time part but the reason i want to keep the type as date is because i need to do sorting on the column. If the do the convert to varchar stuff in sql then the sorting on the page is done on string values instead of date type values.  

Please advice

Comment: @Amit - You need to use a format string on the gridview column. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply [a format string](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223012815/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/kathykam/archive/2006/09/29/.net-format-string-102_3a00_-datetime-format-string.aspx) to your gridview column to only display the date part. An example of such a string would be `dd MMMM yyyy`

Is this an ASP.NET gridview? If so there is example [code here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/137_How_to_format_DateTime_in_GridView_BoundColumn_and_TemplateColumn.aspx).

Comment: well i m using asp.net but i am using devexpress controls for gridview so they do not have support for what is done in the articles you have pointed out. Appreciated your reply

Comment: @Amit - I'm sure they will do. Have a look in the help file for "format string".

Comment: Def better to format the data in the GUI rather than on the db.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

select cast(convert(char(11), getdate(), 113) as datetime)

Comment: Cheers for the reply but its not working for me. I get this result back fom the query 
2010-08-04 00:00:00.000

i don't want trailling zero's but i want to keep the type as date

Comment: Try changing those values like 

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
```

OR

```
Declare @datetime datetime
set @datetime = getdate()
SELECT convert(varchar, @datetime, 101)
```

[DateTime Formats](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

**EDIT:**

- SQL server 2008 has this
  functionality, if you can upgrade.
- Just make sure to save 00:00:00 in
  your table and remove time part in
- Return datetime and format it in your
  grid or in your code.

Comment: But i don't want my column as varchar i want to keep it as datetime

Comment: @Amit, I did not realize that you don't want to convert it. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you could upgrade to SQL2008, that has a separate time command.

I see you say you want to keep it as a datetime object, so as far as I can see if you can't upgrade to 2008 then you are stuck with the zeros

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove time part from thr `datetime` datatype field.

Only thing you can do is to cast it to the `date` or `varchar` datatype before output or to set time part to 00:00:00 before insert/update.

Example:

the statement:

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

returns only date

Comment: yea but i m using sql 2005 and we do not have date in it. My bad

Comment: so, the only way is convert to (n)varchar :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

Why do you care if the database is saving the exact time or 00:00:00?

When you query this field(inside or outside the DB) you can ignore the time value and show only the date...

Again, say what you are trying to do... I believe it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update mytable set mydatetime=convert(datetime,convert(char(10),mydatetime,103),103)**

This will update your table. Hope that is what your looking for.

103: Format datetime as dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Yes, this way he can keep his field as a datetime field and not  varchar but he will lose the time information. Using this query the data will convert from eg. 04/08/2010 13:45:03 to 04/08/2010. If he doesn't want to lose the time, he could use:

Select convert(datetime,convert(char(10),mydatetime,103),103) from mytable