# How SQL's convert function work when converting datetime to float?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

why the out put of this query:

```
declare @currentDate as datetime
    set @currentDate ='01/07/2010'

select convert(float, @currentdate)
```

...is 40183 ?

So for those who are getting confuse with my question, my question is How to know the result of above query without executing it ?

Comment: what else were you expecting???

Comment: what exactly do you need to do?

Comment: i was expecting error, i want to know how it convert datetime to float, internally how it work.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: @Saif: link is quite informative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DateTime is often represented as a day count from a pre-determined date (generally know as the epoch) on the integer part and the percentage of the day elapsed since mid-night on the fractional part.

SQL Server is not the exception to this, thus the conversion to Float makes a lot of sense.  Day 0 is Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 (AFAIK, in no particular time-zone, so you shall consider it "local time").

So, you can try this:

```
declare @ADate DateTime;
set @ADate = '19000101 00:00:00';
select CONVERT(float, @ADate);  --should print 0
set @ADate = '19000101 12:00:00';
select CONVERT(float, @ADate);  --should print 0.5
set @ADate = '19001231 06:00:00';
select CONVERT(float, @ADate);  --should print 364.25
```

So, for your results, 40183 days has been passed since 01/01/1900 00:00:00 and 01/07/2010 00:00:00

Clarification: Unix like systems use a different approach to store datetimes: Seconds since Unix epoch (Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), which is more known as epoch time.

[Edit]
Date format on this response was changed to YYYYMMDD format on 20140416, after some new years of experience with SQL Server (and as @Damien said in his comment) this is the only safe format.

Comment: about your date format - the safe way to specify a date and time is to do YYYY-MM-DD, and to use a 'T' instead of a space, to separate the date and time components (just FYI really)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I used to work with YYYY-MM-DD date format on all major database engines... but (believe it or not) MS-SQL Express 2008 in a Windows 7 Business 32bit Spanish, wants it in YYYY-DD-MM format!!  (just FYI really) :D

Comment: if it's just a date, then YYYYMMDD is the only safe, unambiguous, format (no dashes). Of course, if you use datetime2 or the other newer types, then all of the rules change yet again :-)

Answer (score 5):

DateTime values are actually stored as two four-byte integers under the hood. The first four-byte integer represents the number of days since 1900-01-01. The second four-byte integer stores the number of milliseconds since midnight. When you convert a datetime into a float, the decimal portion represents the percentage of the 24-day that has past. Thus, 0.5 represents noon.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically converting the `datetime` to an OLE Date.  There's a decent description of the process in the documentation for `System.DateTime.ToOADate()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx

The quick explanation is that the integer part is the number of days since 12/30/1899.  The fractional part (zero in this case) is the time divided by 24.

Comment: Actually in TSQL is from 01/01/1900, everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you understand the TSQL implementation (or implement your own):

```
DECLARE
    @date DATETIME = '20180125 09:15:30.549',
    @date_dec DECIMAL (26,10) = 43123.3857702546

SELECT
    CAST(@date_dec AS DATETIME) AS [TSQL cast to DATETIME],
    CAST(@date AS DECIMAL (26,10)) AS [TSQL cast to DECIMAL]

SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, FLOOR(@date_dec), 
        DATEADD(HOUR, FLOOR(@date_dec % 1 * 24), 
            DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR((@date_dec % 1 * 24) % 1 * 60), 
                DATEADD(SECOND, FLOOR(((@date_dec % 1 * 24) % 1 * 60) % 1 * 60), 
                    DATEADD(MILLISECOND, FLOOR((((@date_dec % 1 * 24) % 1 * 60) % 1 * 60) % 1 * 1000), '19000101')
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS [Manual cast to DATETIME],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', @date) 
    + (
        DATEPART(HOUR, @date) 
        + (
            DATEPART(MINUTE, @date) 
            + (
                DATEPART(SECOND, @date)
                + DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @date) / CAST(1000 AS FLOAT)
              ) / CAST(60 AS FLOAT)
          ) / CAST(60 AS FLOAT)
      ) / CAST(24 AS DECIMAL (26,10)) AS [Manual cast to DECIMAL]
```

Note that the result is not always the same as TSQL loses precision on last millisecond digit.