# How can I convert datatime to int data type with GETDATE() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two problems.

- How can I get today's date without time?
- How can I convert `datetime` type into `int` type?

Comment: Have you do a quick search before asking the question here ?

Comment: Yes but I can't get the good answer

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/113055 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141515

Comment: What integer do you want for which date?  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following queries:

> Q1:How can I get Today's date without time ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

> Q2:How can I convert datetime type into int type ?

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) * 10000 + MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100 + DAY(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as a decimal value, you did not specify how you want to construct your int.

Do you want the actual decimal value ?
you can see the value like this

```
select CONVERT(float, getdate())
```

if you only need the date, then this can help

```
select convert(int, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
```

or

```
select convert(int, getdate(), 112)
```

Both methods will return an int value for the given date.
For `22/06/2021` this will return `44367`

or if you just want to convert the formatted value, then the easiest way is this

```
select convert(int, Convert(CHAR(8), getdate(), 112))
```

For `22/06/2021` this will return `20210622`