# select statement using Between with datetime type does not retrieve all fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm facing a strange query result and I want to ask you why I'm facing this issue.

I store some datetime data into **TestTable** as following :

```
creation_time
-----------------------
2010-07-10 00:01:43.000
2010-07-11 00:01:43.000
2010-07-12 00:01:43.000
```

This table is created and filled as following :

```
create table TestTable(creation_time datetime);
Insert into  TestTable values('2010-07-10 00:01:43.000');
Insert into  TestTable values('2010-07-11 00:01:43.000');
Insert into  TestTable values('2010-07-12 00:01:43.000');
```

when I execute this query , I get two rows only instead of three as I expected:

```
SELECT *  FROM TestTable
WHERE  creation_time BETWEEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2010-07-10',111) -- remove time part
                     and      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2010-07-12',111) -- remove time part
```

Or if I execute this query , the same issue ..

```
SELECT *  FROM TestTable
WHERE  CONVERT(datetime,creation_time,111) BETWEEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2010-07-10',111) -- remove time part
                                              and      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2010-07-12',111) -- remove time part
```

**My Question :**

- Why the last row **('2010-07-12 00:01:43.000')** does not appear in
  the result even if I set the date range to cover all the day from **2010-07-10 to 2010-07-12**?
- I use Sql server 2005 express edition with windows xp 32-bits.
- I'm trying to don't use a workaround solution such as increasing the date range to cover additional day to get the days I want.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the time part from creation_time as well. Just use the same `CONVERT` if it works.

Currently you're asking if 2010-07-12 00:01:43.000 is less than 2010-07-12 00:00:00.000, which is not true.

Comment: I did that , but no result ? I'll update my question to mention this point . thanks

Comment: I found a method to remove the time part :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server, Thanks matti and thank you guys , I will choose this answer since it's the first useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

it does not show the date because you have removed the time part, which would make the date equivalent to `'2010-07-12 00:00:00.000'` and since the last row is greater than this, so it is not displaying in the query results.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable
WHERE  creation_time BETWEEN
  convert(datetime, convert(char, '2010-07-10', 106))-- remove time part
  and **DATEADD**(day, 1, convert(datetime, convert(char, '2010-07-**11**', 106))) -- remove time part and add 1 day
```

This script will return all between 2010-07-10 00:00:00 and 2010-07-12 00:00:00. Basically this means all items created in 2 days: 2010-07-10 and 2010-07-11.

Answer (score 1):

Converting columns in your table for comparison can be costly and cause indexes to not be used.  If you have a million rows in your table and you have an index on creation_time,  you will be doing an index scan and converting all million values to a string for comparison.

I find it better to use >= the start date and < (end date + 1 day):

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE creation_time >= '2010-07-10'
    AND creation_time < dateadd(day, 1, '2010-07-12')
```

And the reason your second one may not work is because format 111 uses slashes ("2010/07/10"), format 120 uses dashes ("2010-07-10").  Your converts aren't doing anything to your start and end date because you are converting a string to varchar, not a date.  If you did this, it might work, but I would still recommend not doing the conversion:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, creation_time, 111) BETWEEN
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, '2010-07-10'), 111) -- remove time part
    and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, '2010-07-12'), 111) -- remove time part
```

Answer (score 0):

Date/time inclusive between 7/10/2010 and 7/12/2010:

```
SELECT *  FROM TestTable 
WHERE  creation_time BETWEEN  
 CONVERT(VARCHAR,'2010-07-10',101) -- remove time part                      
  and CONVERT(VARCHAR,'2010-07-13',101) -- remove time part
```