# SQL return first day of last month and current month @ 00:00:00

Tags: sql

I am using this code

```
declare @mydate datetime select @mydate = getdate()
declare @startdate varchar(20)  SELECT @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))-1),DATEADD(mm,-1,@mydate)),120)
declare @enddate varchar(20) SELECT @EndDate = CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),120)
Select @startdate as 'Start Date', @enddate as 'End Date'
```

To determine the first day of the previous and current month for a report, but it gives a time based on the current time.  How can I get

```
2011-04-01 00:00:00
&
2011-05-01 00:00:00
```

?

Comment: @MT0 Since I asked mine first shouldn't that question be a duplicate of mine? I get updates and long-tail rep of this. I was first.

Comment: Yes, you asked the question first but the other question has some more detailed answers. If it was the other way round then I would have voted to close the other question. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers

Comment: I was not aware. The meta has spoken! I also agree. My reasons were selfish. The logic from MSE wins. I vote to be flagged as dup. Thanks for your democratic response and "don't be a jerk"-ness. I love you. OK Bye!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [DATEADD/DATEDIFF trick:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server/1177529#1177529)

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0),
   DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: +1 for not using the string method. However, if he's using MSSQL2008 he can just convert to `DATE`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your last statement to the one below to achieve the results:

```
Select SUBSTRING(@startdate,1,11) + '00:00:00' as 'Start Date', 
       SUBSTRING(@enddate,1,11)+ '00:00:00' as 'End Date'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL Data base

```
# First day of the previous month
SELECT concat(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),' ','00:00:00') as 'PreviousMonthFirstDay';

# Last day of the previous month
SELECT concat(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),' ','00:00:00') as 'PreviousMonthLastDay';
```

Reference [MySQL First day of previous month](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,353205)

Answer (score 0):

From SQL2012, there is a new function introduced called EOMONTH. Using this function the first and last day of the month can be easily found.

select DATEADD(DD,1,EOMONTH(Getdate(),-1)) firstdayofmonth, EOMONTH(Getdate()) lastdayofmonth