# ObjectResult<Nullable<DateTime>> to IEnumerable<DateTime>?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ienumerable

I've attached a stored procedure (see [my previous question w/proc code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088933/return-cast-convert-values-as-datetime-from-a-distinct-year-month-query-in-a)) to my Entity Framework model with function import,  selecting "Scalars: DateTime" to get a collection of DateTimes as the return type. I am calling that in my repository:

```
return _DataContext.GetPubsDistinctMonthYears(pubType, pubId).AsEnumerable();
```

I need the repository method to return IEnumerable; however, the function is returning `ObjectResult<Nullable<DateTime>` (with the correct DateTime values in it), and if I cast it as IEnumerable, the result is just null.

"Safe cast" doesn't work either:

```
return _DataContext.GetPubsDistinctMonthYears(pubType, pubId) as IEnumerable<DateTIme>;
```

**QUESTION**
So what do I need to do either/both in the stored procedure and the repository to get my IEnumerable??

Comment: Please edit your question with more realistic code - `return = ` is never valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want something like:

```
return _DataContext.GetPubsDistinctMonthYears(pubType, pubId)
                   .Select(x => x.Value);
```

That will go bang if there are any null values though. To ignore null values, you could use:

```
return _DataContext.GetPubsDistinctMonthYears(pubType, pubId)
                   .Where(x => x.HasValue)
                   .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: .Where(x => x.HasValue) was the ticket. Note though: I still needed AsEnumerable();

Comment: @Faust: If `GetPubsDistinctMonthYears` returns `ObjectResult<T>` you shouldn't need `AsEnumerable`, as that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. What was going wrong when you didn't call `AsEnumerable`?