# store date only, not the the time in datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, date

This is a trivial question, I added a field

```
Alter table MyTbl add datecreated smalldatetime default CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),101)
```

When I go check the new field, it shows not only the date but also time. I check the table definition (right click on table -> Modify in SSMS) and it does say the default value as GETDATE() [it discarded the convert(...) by default]. Why is this so. Is there a way to give a default date only to datetime field and not the time.

I ended up leaving the time field as it is because it is better to see what is going on in the table esp in initial test phase.

Comment: I would still capture the time myself, and use formatting to only provide the date.

Comment: +1 @OMG - it's easy to ignore data you don't need but impossible to get it back once you discard it.

Comment: youve choosen the incorrect answer.t zeroing out with string manipulation is worse . my answer is more correct dealing with datetime operations merely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your `ALTER` statement, and it works as you expect;  when I enter a row without including `datecreated`, it sets the value to the date with a time of `00:00:00`.

The fact that you checked the table definition and it says the default is `GETDATE()` leads me to believe the column already existed and your `ALTER` failed.

Comment: I just ran a test myself, and `INSERT` ... `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),101)` to a Datetime field sets the time value to midnight.

Comment: yes verified with a new datecreated column. It does shows time 00:00:00. Don't know what was wrong. It does show only GetDATE() in default value though.

Answer (score 1):

this will reset the time section  to zero

```
DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0)
```

Comment: The OP already has zero'd out time.  When converted to `varchar` it loses the time portion of the `datetime`.  This should give the same results as the OP already has.

Comment: I was the upvote on this. Yes, the OP zerod out the time, but zeroing out with string manipulation is worse than this method. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server )

Comment: @gbn , Are you familiar with certificates and symmetric keys permission in sql server ?

Comment: I am not sure how i will this code. But I decided to keep the time info for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you are converting the datetime returned from `getdate()` to a `varchar(10)`, there is another implicit cast from `varchar(10)` to `datetime`, as it is the datatype for your field.

You need to have the `datecreated` field datatype a `varchar(10)`.

Your `alter table` statement should be:

```
Alter table MyTbl add datecreated varchar(10) default CONVERT(varchar(10),GetDate(),101)
```