# sql server:how to get just the date component?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get the date component in this query. How can I create a query that is the most efficient?

```
UPDATE  myTable

WHERE
    [DateTime] = @DateTime
AND
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL 2008 has a [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) datatype:

```
CAST(@DateTime AS DATE)
```

I cannot put it in better context without more of your `UPDATE` statement