# Convert datatime with time to datetime with no time in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Suppose a table column MyDate is datetime. then following data can be saved to db:

```
2011-11-24 12:43:27.723  
2011-11-24 12
```

I want to convert `2011-11-24 12:43:27.723` to `2011-11-24` with no time, I tried following way:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(INT, MyDate))
```

Interesting is: `2011-11-24 12:43:27.723` is converted to `2011-11-25` instead of `2011-11-24`.

How to resolve it?

Comment: "2011-11-24 12" won't be *stored* in a datetime column

Answer (score 4):

Use built in [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) type which is available since Sql Server 2008:

```
SELECT CAST('2011-11-24 12:43:27.723' as Date)
```

Output:

```
2011-11-24
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is regarding SQL 2008 if you are using an earlier version of SQL Server I tend to use this approach:

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CAST('2011-11-24 12:43:27.273' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Which outputs:

```
2011-11-24 00:00:00.000
```