# Remove time from dates in table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a number of rows in the table, which `datetime` column values contain both date and time. I need to remove time part from them. By another words, if value is `2006-08-10 01:00:00.000`, it should be replaced with `2006-08-10 00:00:00.000`.
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By casting to the new `Date` type in SQL server 2008 the time part will be removed.

```
SELECT CAST(tbl.ColumnName As Date)
FROM tbl
```