# Type DATE is not a defined system type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Trying this to cast time away

```
   select CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103) [Reg Date], Regs
    from (
          select cast(SetupDateTime as DATE) [Reg Date1]
               , COUNT(distinct ID) [Regs]
          from dbo.tbl_User
          where cast(SetupDateTime as DATE) 
                between cast((DATEADD (dd , -7 , GETDATE())) AS DATE) 
                    and cast((DATEADD (dd , -1 , GETDATE())) AS DATE)
          group by cast(SetupDateTime as DATE)
        ) a
    order by a.[Reg Date1]
```

but I get this error

> Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: Which **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: And why do you even need to cast `SetupDateTime` to something else?? What datatype is `SetupDateTime` in your table??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using SQL Server 2005 or earlier. Data type [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) was introduced in SQL Server 2008. Try to cast to [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) instead.

Have a look at this question on how to remove the time part from a datetime. [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: I have this problem now thi sis the query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sybase ASE, what you need is [`datetime`](http://www.comsci.us/sybase/date_fmt.html).