# Need to calculate by rounded time or date figure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have 2 data columns in Ms Sql 2008

uniqueidentifier column as ID and a datetime column with a few results like follows.

```
2011-11-06 18:02:18.030
2011-11-06 18:02:18.373
2011-11-06 18:02:57.560
2011-11-06 18:02:58.593
2011-11-06 18:03:01.717
2011-11-06 18:03:02.373
2011-11-06 18:03:03.407
```

Aside from the complexity of the ID column.
I'm only interested in grouping the data based om intervals per

```
minutes(1,5,10,15,30)
hours (1,2)
days(1,5,10)
months(1,2)
```

The results should be floored or otherwise to yield only 1 unique per interval
As follows

```
2011-11-06 18:02:00 (1 Minute)
2011-11-06 18:03:00 (1 Minute)
2011-11-06 18:04:00 (1 Minute)
2011-11-06 18:05:00 (1 Minute)
2011-11-06 18:06:00 (1 Minute)
```

Or per day

```
2011-11-06 00:00:00 (1 Day)
2011-11-07 00:00:00 (1 Day)
2011-11-08 00:00:00 (1 Day)
2011-11-09 00:00:00 (1 Day)
2011-11-10 00:00:00 (1 Day)
```

etc.

Any constructive suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the same technique to round to any date interval. This relies on integer division

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, foo), 0),              -- whole minute
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, foo) / 5 * 5, 0),      -- 5 minute
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, foo) / 10 * 10, 0),    -- 10 minute
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, foo) / 15 * 15, 0),    -- 15 minute
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, foo) / 30 * 30, 0),    -- 30 minute

    DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, foo), 0),                  -- whole hour
    DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, foo) / 2 * 2, 0),          -- 2 hour

    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, foo), 0),                    -- whole day
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, foo) / 5 * 5, 0),            -- 5 day
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, foo) / 10 * 10, 0),          -- 10 day

    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, foo), 0),                -- whole month
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, foo) / 2 * 2, 0)         -- 2 month
FROM
    @dates;
```

Comment: That is just so cool, and a very neat way of accomplishing this.  I must say that I wish there were something built in to accomplish it, but hey, your approach does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that your DateTime column named mydatetime

***For minutes***

if only **floored**

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(minute, mydatetime), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, mydatetime), CONVERT(varchar, mydatetime, 112)))
from YourTable
```

if **ROUNDED**, then it is much simpler

```
select DISTINCT CAST(mydatetime as smalldatetime)
from YourTable
```

***For hours***
in just the similar way

***for days***

```
select DISTINCT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, mydatetime, 112) as date)
from YourTable
```

***For months***

```
select DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(mydatetime), CONVERT(varchar, mydatetime, 112))
from YourTable
```

Comment: What about the other intervals)? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177529/27535 about best ways to do this