# SQL for obtaining data any previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi im still fairly new to SQL script and i have written some below to fetch what i hope will be ALL of the previous months data when run at any given date, regardless of the number of days in a month

The table date format is 2013-05-10 00:00:00.000

im just after an expert eye to look at the script and advise if i have got it right or wrong and where if i have please:

```
SELECT 
[Circuit Number]
,[Request Number]
,[RequestDate]
FROM [QuoteBase].[dbo].[Requests]
WHERE RequestType LIKE 'Cancel%' 
AND DATEPART(mm, [RequestDate]) = DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, [RequestDate]) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate()))
```

Comment: Which engine and version?

Comment: It seems nothing wrong with your query

Comment: Since the dates are converted to dateparts, it will not be able to use any indexes, resulting in a full table scan.

Comment: @ahkvk: which is why I gave 3 conditions in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no SQL expert but try this:

```
SELECT [Circuit Number]
,[Request Number]
,[RequestDate]
FROM Requests
WHERE RequestType LIKE 'Cancel%'
AND DATEDIFF(mm,Requestdate , GETDATE())=1
AND DATEDIFF(yy,Requestdate, GETDATE())=0
```

See my [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4deac/1)

Explanation:

```
DATEDIFF(mm,Requestdate , GETDATE())=1 (Only Request previous Month of the Current Date)
```

Next condition:

```
DATEDIFF(yy,Requestdate, GETDATE())=0 (Only in same year as Current Date)
```

However, if you want just the previous month regardless if it is the same year as Current Date or not then you could remove the second condition, like:

```
SELECT [Circuit Number]
,[Request Number]
,[RequestDate]
FROM Requests
WHERE RequestType LIKE 'Cancel%'
AND DATEDIFF(mm,Requestdate , GETDATE())=1
```

See the [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4deac/3) for this.

For example if the CurrentDate is `2013-01-19` then any `December 2012` request will be included despite that it is not of the same year but is obviously of previous month.

Comment: yes i believe that is what i want IE Always the previous months data whether we are in january (we get Decmbers data from the previous year) or july (we get Junes data).

Comment: @MoiD101 then try my 2nd query.

Comment: With a predicate on a function, no index can be used. See my link about SQL programming errors

Comment: @gbn thank you for your comment and the reference sir, it's worth the read. But I think the OP just wants a simple and straightforward solution that works for him.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    [Circuit Number]
   ,[Request Number]
   ,[RequestDate]
FROM
   [QuoteBase].[dbo].[Requests]
WHERE
   RequestType LIKE 'Cancel%' 
   AND
   [RequestDate] >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0);  --year
   AND
   [RequestDate] >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 32, GETDATE()), 0);   -- start last month
   AND
   [RequestDate] < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0);   -- start this month
```

This uses the technique fronhere to find start of month: [Need to calculate by rounded time or date figure in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722022/need-to-calculate-by-rounded-time-or-date-figure-in-sql-server/8723311#8723311)

Also, don't use function on predicates. See number 2 here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

In this case, an index like this will be useful

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Whatever ON
         QuoteBase (RequestDate, RequestType)
            INCLUDE ([Circuit Number], [Request Number])
```