# Efficient sliding window sum over a database table

Tags: sql, database-design, sliding-window

A database has a `transactions` table with columns: `account_id`, `date`, `transaction_value` (signed integer). Another table (`account_value`) stores the current total value of each account, which is the sum of all `transaction_value`s per account. It is updated with a trigger on the `transactions` table (i.e., INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs to `transactions` fire the trigger to change the `account_value`.)

A new requirement is to calculate the account's total transaction value *only over the last 365 days*. Only the current running total is required, not previous totals. This value will be requested often, almost as often as the `account_value`.

How would you implement this "sliding window sum" efficiently? A new table is ok. Is there a way to avoid summing over a year's range every time?

Comment: Are you maintaining a record of all of these running totals for all the different days of the year?  Such that you can see the values for a whole month in a single report?

Comment: To paraphrase Dems, do you simply want "last 365 days from today" or do you want "last 365 days from each day in some other range"?

Comment: @gbn, Only sum back from today.

Comment: @Dems, only sum back from today, no need for sums for every day.

Comment: @user1147339: then use my solution: don't precompute it

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with standard windowing functions:

```
SELECT account_id,
       sum(transaction_value) over (partition by account_id order by date)
FROM transactions
```

The `order by` inside the `over()` claues makes the sum a "sliding sum".

For the "only the last 356 days" you'd need a second query that will limit the rows in the WHERE clause.

The above works in PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2 and (I think) Teradata. SQL Server does not support the order by in the window definition (the upcoming Denali version will AFAIK)

Comment: FYI, you're correct about OVER clause limitations in SQL Server with aggregate functions. Only PARTITION BY can be used

Comment: @gbn: you mean for SQL Server?

Comment: The OP currently seems to be maintaining a track of the running totals over time.  It would seem to imply that reports being run may pull these running totals for multiple different days at a time.  Such as viewing the changes in the running over a week, or month, or even year.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this?

```
SELECT
   SUM(transaction_value), account_id
FROM
   transactions t
WHERE
   -- SQL Server, Sybase       t.DATE >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
   -- MySQL            t.DATE >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY
   account_id;
```

You may want to remove the time component from the date expressions using DATE (MySQL) or [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177529/27535) in SQL Server

Comment: Sybase ASE is the first as well :P

Comment: @aF. I think the OP wants a report showing the year_to_date running total for every day.  So a report covering a year would have 365 different running totals over different 365 day ranges, and that's per account.  It really is a headache, and a trigger based caching of the current values if often Much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If queries of the transactions table are more frequent than inserts to the transactions table, then perhaps a view is the way to go?

Comment: Or a compromise: a materialized view or indexed view, depending on the RDBMS in question?

Comment: Running Totals are extremely expensive.  This trigger based approach will use less resource that a direct query, even if reads are 100 times less frequent than writes.

Comment: But a trigger-based approach can't guarantee that the totals are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a one-off script to populate the existing table with values for the preceding year for each existing record - that will need to run for the whole of the previous year for each record generated.

Once the rolling year column is populated, one alternative to summing the previous year would be to derive each new record's value as the previous record's rolling year value, plus the transaction value(s) since the last update, minus the transaction values between one year prior to the last update and one year ago from now.

I suggest trying both approaches against realistic test data to see which will perform better - I would expect summing the whole year to perform at least as well where data is relatively sparse, while the difference method may work better if data is to be frequently updated on each account.

Answer (score 0):

I'll avoid any actual SQL here as it varies a lot depending on the variety of SQL that you are using.

You say that you have a trigger to maintain the existing running total.

I presume that it also (or perhaps a nightly process) creates new daily records in the `account_value` table.  Then INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs fire the trigger to add or subtract from the existing running total?

The only changes you need to make are:
- add a new field, "yearly_value" or something
- have the existing trigger update that in the same way as the existing field
- use gbn's type of answer to create today's records (or however far you backdate)
- but initialise each new daily record in a slightly different way...

When you insert a new row for a new day, it should be initialised to `yesterday's value` - `the value 365 days ago`.  After that, the behavior should be identical to what you're already used to.