# group by function not working fine with datetime

Tags: sql-server

Hi i need  group the records based on the time stmap

```
datetime column
2011-11-23 06:08:50.000
2011-11-23 06:08:50.000
2011-11-23 06:21:06.000
2011-11-23 06:21:06.000
2011-11-23 06:21:06.000
2011-11-23 07:00:18.000
```

right now  it displays like this when i do  group by function

```
2011-11-23 06:08:50.000    2
2011-11-23 06:21:06.000    3
2011-11-23 07:00:18.000    1
```

ar per  my result i need  to get
**2011-11-23     6**

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: Duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server) because the question is about removing time from datetime. Not GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Group by CONVERT(varchar(13), dateTimeColumn, 121)
```

This converts the time to a string matching pattern `YYYY-MM-DD HH`, which seems to be what you want, e.g. `'2012-01-31 12'`.

That format will also sort and compare in the natural way.

For a resolution of days, use varchar(10), hours varchar(13), minutes, use varchar(16), seconds varchar(19). Essentially you are truncating the string at the relevant point.

Comment: There are better ways, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server/1177529#1177529

Comment: @gbn, there are more ***correct*** ways, but this one is extremely easy to use, to read, and to remember.

Comment: I dunno, a simply CAST to date (as per @Alex K.) is quite clean. Anyway, it is important if you aggregated over a million rows, or have to cast back to datetime

Answer (score 2):

In 2008;

```
select cast(f as date), count(*) 
from t
group by cast(f as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Cast(Floor(Cast(DateTimeColumn as float))as datetime), Count(*)
From Yourtable
Group By Cast(Floor(Cast(DateTimeColumn as float))as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
group by day(date_column), month(date_column), year(date_column)
```

you can later do (with the proper casting) on your select:

```
select  day(date_column)+ '\' + month(date_column) + '\' +  year(date_column)
```