# SQL Server 2008 - Date format still retain date datatype

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

How can I convert the date 2009-01-27 11:47:00.000 to 24 Jan 2009 but also be able to retain date datatype to be able to sort as date not alphabetically?

I.e. date sort order

```
24 Jan 2009
03 Feb 2009
```

NOT

```
03 Feb 2009
24 Jan 2009
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to a string in your select, but still order by on the actual column:

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(11), Orders.ShipDate, 6) As FormatedDate
FROM Orders
Order by ShipDate Desc
```

Comment: Thank for your response. How about if I don't want to order by the time stamp, as I to order by date then by customer_no?

Comment: See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server).  If you are using SQL Server 2008, you would do **Order by cast(ShipDate as DATE) Desc** or if using and older SQL Server version **Order by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ShipDate), 0)**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PrettyDate = CONVERT(CHAR(11), ShipDate, 106)
  FROM dbo.Orders
  ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, ShipDate), customer_no;
```