# Best way to compare dates without time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, utc

```
select * from sampleTable 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateCreated,101) 
=     CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST('Feb 15 2012  7:00:00:000PM' AS DATETIME),101)
```

I want to compare date without time

Is above query is ok? or other better solution you suggest

- I am using SQL Server 2005
- Date saved in UTC format on server
- Users against this data belongs different timezone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Don't use convert - that involves strings for no reason. A trick is that a datetime is actually a numeric, and the days is the integer part (time is the decimal fraction); hence the day is the **FLOOR** of the value: this is then just math, not strings - much faster

```
declare @when datetime = GETUTCDATE()
select @when -- date + time
declare @day datetime = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@when as float)) as datetime)
select @day -- date only
```

In your case, no need to convert back to datetime; and using a range allows the most efficent comparisons (especially if indexed):

```
declare @when datetime = 'Feb 15 2012  7:00:00:000PM'
declare @min datetime = FLOOR(CAST(@when as float))
declare @max datetime = DATEADD(day, 1, @min)

select * from sampleTable where DateCreated >= @min and DateCreated < @max
```

Comment: Been tested, and keeping in the datetime domain is best http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177529/27535

Comment: @gbn Interesting. It is pretty close, though, between the two. The key take-away point from that: don't use strings ;p

Comment: I also prefer staying within datetime (rather than casting to float) as I prefer to treat datetime's numeric representation as an implementation detail (i.e., that days is the integer part of a `datetime`).

Answer (score 65):

Simple Cast to `Date` will resolve the problem.

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '04/01/2016 12:01:31'

DECLARE @Date2 datetime = '04/01/2016'

SELECT CAST(@Date as date)

SELECT CASE When (CAST(@Date as date) = CAST(@Date2 as date)) Then 1 Else 0 End
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT .......
FROM ........
WHERE 
CAST(@DATETIMEVALUE1 as DATE) = CAST(@DATETIMEVALUE2 as DATE)
```

The disadvantage is that you are casting the filter column.

If there is an index on the filter column, then, since you are casting, the SQL engine can no longer use indexes to filter the date more efficiently.

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

Don't convert your Date to a varchar and compare because string comparisson is not fast.

It is much faster if you use `>=` and `<` to filter your `DateCreated` column.

If you have no parameter (like in your sample, a string) you should use the ISO Format `<Year><Month><Day>`.

#### Sample

**According to your sample**

```
DECLARE @startDate DateTime
DECLARE @endDate DateTime

SET @startDate = '20120215'
SET @endDate = DATEADD(d,1,@startDate)

SELECT * FROM sampleTable 
WHERE DateCreated >= @startDate AND DateCreated < @endDate
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: minor: re the `where` construction - it would need testing, but I would **expect** an obvious range-based approach (`>= @min and < @max`) to work better, especially for indexed data.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it makes sense if he want data between two dates but he wants only data from one day. not ?

Comment: the range can be exactly one day, trivially; but it should allow direct use of the index, rather than having to do any computations per row.

Comment: SQL Server chose the same plan for both - IO stats are the same

Comment: Yes my result is the same. The Optimizer is awesome ;)

Comment: ah, no: reads are the same - but CPU for the second is much higher: http://pastie.org/3393454 - meaning: the range approach is more efficient

Comment: In my plan i can't see a significant difference.

Comment: For those of you who likes performance, my solution is faster according to my test

Comment: While I agree with your first statement (don't convert to varchar), I disagree that applying dateadd/datediff directly to the column is the best approach. Not just for efficiency (I understand the optimizer might make sense of this, but clearly the CPU still has to work harder), but also because you have to change your methodology if you need to get data for more than a day. Open-ended range is much more flexible and allows you to be consistent. Some other thoughts here : https://sqlblog.org/dates

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thats right, the CPU has more work. My answer is updated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use 112 CONVERT's format

```
select * 
from sampleTable 
where 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateCreated,112) 
=     CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST('Feb 15 2012  7:00:00:000PM' AS DATETIME),112)
```

**or**

if your sql server version 2008+ use `DATE` type

```
select * from sampleTable 
where CONVERT(DATE,DateCreated) 
=     CONVERT(DATE,CAST('Feb 15 2012  7:00:00:000PM' AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score -1):

declare @DateToday Date= '2019-10-1';
print @DateToday;

print Abs(datediff(day, @DateToday,CAST('oct 1 2019  7:00:00:000PM' AS DATETIME))) < 3

this is compare whin 3 days.

i test this on SQL Server 2014, it works.

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from sampleTable 
where date_created ='20120215'
```

This will also compare your column with the particular date 
without taking time into account

Comment: casting to varchars and then comparing is way slower than comparing dates

Comment: This will not work. The OP want all rows for the given date, not only the `2012-02-15 00:00.000` data.