# what should be order of YEAR() MONTH() DAY() in a tsql where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-designer

What should be the order of YEAR DAY MONTH in a where clause of tsql?

```
Select * from TABLE_NAME 
WHERE
YEAR(COLUMN_NAME)=YEAR(GETDATE()) --1
and DAY(COLUMN_NAME)=DAY(GETDATE()) --2
and MONTH(COLUMN_NAME)=MONTH(GETDATE()) --3
```

Does the order improve the run time of query?
how does a tsql execute this statement?

Comment: Are you trying to do a date comparison whilst ignoring the time? ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427469/compare-dates-in-t-sql-ignoring-the-time-part ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308635/best-way-to-compare-dates-without-time-in-sql-server

Comment: Which version of sqlserver are you using ?

Comment: How does sql parse a where clause? right to left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to improve performance, then you are doing it wrong. The filters that you are using won't use an index (if there exists one on `COLUMN_NAME`) because you are applying a function to them. The right way to do it would be to compare that column directly against `GETDATE()` (on this case). This is a better way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME >= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
AND COLUMN_NAME < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),1)
```

Comment: @t-clausen.dk No, you are wrong. The `GETDATE()` will be evaluated only once and so will the `DATEADD()` function calls, in this query.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk please find examples. In every situation I've seen, SQL Server is smart enough to only evaluate GETDATE() once, so I'm not sure how it could lead to a slow query.