# get only date from date variable sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

**Date Format**

[image]

Problem: I just want date - no time.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT SubjectIndex, LetterNo, DateOfIssue 
FROM [CircularKeeper]  
ORDER BY DateOfIssue DESC
```

After removing the time part I want it to be ordered descending.

I am binding the data using a `SqlDataSource` to a listsview and displaying the date in a label control.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it a number of ways, in 2008 I'd go with:

```
SELECT SubjectIndex,LetterNo, CAST(DateOfIssue AS DATE) AS DateOfIssue
FROM [CircularKeeper]  
ORDER BY DateOfIssue DESC
```

As there is now a DATE data type - if you don't actually store times in that field in the table, then you might want to consider changing the datatype from DATETIME to DATE instead - saves the CASTing like this and uses less space (3 bytes instead of 8).

You could also just do this in the UI by returning the DATETIME as you currently are, and making sure you format the dates appropriately before rendering.

**Update:**
I would recommend returning the DATE as a DATE from the query - so return the data in it's strongly typed form. If for presentation purposes you need it formatted a certain way, I'd recommend applying the formatting in your presentation logic.

Comment: actually i am using DATE but still i get the time part  :(

Comment: @user1150440 - in that case, you need to format the data returned into the format you want in the code that's binding/rendering the data to produce the output. You could return a formatted string from the query, but IMHO it's usually best to return the data as-is and leave the formatting down to the presentation layer

Comment: @user1150440: that is a *display format* problem, not a SQL problem

Comment: how can i fix this?? kindly help me.

Comment: also i want  the date in dd/mm/yyyy format ...kindly guide me

Comment: `SELECT SubjectIndex,LetterNo,CONVERT(CHAR(11),DateOfIssue,106) AS DateOfIssue FROM [CircularKeeper]  ORDER BY DateOfIssue DESC` this converts the date but ODER BY dosent work as it is converted to varchar...how can i make the order by work??

Comment: If you're binding the data to an ASP.NET gridview, see: http://forums.asp.net/t/1001482.aspx/1 - if not, please update your Question with details on how the data is rendered

Comment: @AdaTheDev i have updated the question ...kindly give it a look

Comment: `<asp:label id="lblDate" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Your_Date_Column", "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}") %>' />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Formats like below in your select statement

**Option - 1**

```
select Convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) --02/23/2012
select Convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 102) --2012.02.23
select Convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) --23/02/2012
select Convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 104) --23.02.2012
select Convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 105) --23-02-2012
```

---

**Option - 2**

```
select CAST(GETDATE()as date) --2012-02-23
```

---

**C# Code**

```
DateTime dt;
string Temp1 = "Your Date";
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt))
{
     // If it is a valid date
     string date = dt.ToShortDateString();
     string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
}
```

Comment: *never* use varchar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server/1177529#1177529