# Unable to Generate Data from sql server using Date attribute

Tags: sql-server

i need to retrieve data from sql server database using date attribute as shown below

```
SELECT OracleId,FirstName,MiddleName,CoachGroupName 
FROM viewDailyAttendanceInfo where  Createddate = '4/14/2014 ';
```

but, nothing data will be generate, even if the record is found in the DB

Note:- the data type of createddate is datetime.

Comment: Try `createddate >= '20140414' and createddate < '20140415'`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a space in your Date String at the end '4/14/2014 '.

Try removing that space, if that doesn't work try using greater than (>) and less than (<) operators on the date, something like:

```
SELECT OracleId,FirstName,MiddleName,CoachGroupName FROM viewDailyAttendanceInfo where      Createddate >= '4/14/2014' and Createddate < '4/15/2014';
```

But my guess is that it's because of the space in your date.

Comment: dear, its not working. and i need to have only one date parameter.

Comment: Have a look at this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955281/sql-where-datetime-column-equals-todays-date