# Select database where datetime>now()?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have 2 questions:

1. How can i select the data from the database `where datetime>now()` by writing php code?
2. if there is the data from the database `where datetime>now()` , i want select the last two value from the database. what should i do?

I'm doing my gps tracking website. At the moment,my page is just select the last data to show the last position on the map. What i want is ,when i login my page, i will see the final position of the vehicle, and if the vehicles moves(mean the datetime of the data in database>now(), i want to select the 2 last updated data frequently to caculate the distance

Comment: please explain what you tried before.

Comment: Please give us an code example of what you've tried and problems you're having and we can help you better.

Comment: This is a simple question, with a very easy answer... But I (among others) will not answer until you do some research on your own. I can link to two other SO questions that answer each of yours. State what you have tried, at a minimum

Comment: I'm doing my gps tracking website. At the moment,my page is just select the last data to show the last position on the map. What i want is ,when i login my page, i will see the final position of the vehicle, and if the vehicles moves(mean the datetime of the data in database>now(), i want to select the 2 last updated data frequently to caculate the distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store *now()* in a variable and then compare using where clause.

Also see [this](https://www.udemy.com/blog/sql-compare-dates/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395459/comparing-results-with-todays-date)

**Update :**`<?php
$timeZone = 'Asia/Kolkata'; //variable for indian timezone 
date_default_timezone_set( $timeZone); //default timezone set to indian time
$now = date("m/d/y G.i:s");
echo $now;
?>`

Check [for date functions in PHP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_date_time_functions.htm)

Comment: I write $now=now(); and then echo $now; but my page announce the now() function is undefined. What should i do

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT columnname 
    FROM tablename 
    WHERE DATE(yourdatefieldname) >= DATE(NOW())";
```

write this in if else