# Why does GetDate() return tomorrow's date?

Tags: sql-server, timezone, getdate

If I do a `select GetDate()` today (October 9, 2017) against a SQL Server 2008 instance the function will return `10/10/2017` i.e. tomorrow's date.
However a `select convert(date, getDate())` will return `9/10/2017`. I don't understand why.

Possibly related: the Microsoft documentation says

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value
>   without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the
>   operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server
>   is running.

What exactly does `without the database time zone offset` mean? My SQL Server is currently in GMT+11.

Comment: This doesn’t sound correct. How are you running this queries? Can you reproduce in SSMS?

Comment: share the solution if it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Try to look out base on given examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395459/comparing-results-with-todays-date)

GetDate() function doesn't check to current time zone it gives yo the computer time.

Try to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP might be help full

Best regards..

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

OR

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME();
```

For system date and time.

Also, get UTC and local time using:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE() As UTCDateTime
```

And

```
SELECT CONVERT( DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, GETUTCDATE()), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS LocalDateTime
```

Comment: I use the last one to convert UTC saved time in cloud-hosted databases to local time. Please suggest better.

Comment: What you wrote is basically `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`.  But if you're saying that instead of the inner `GETUTCDATE()` you'd use a database field, then you're incorrectly assuming that the *current* offset is the same for the one at the time of the value in that field.  To convert correctly, you need either `AT TIME ZONE` (SQL 2016+) or for older SQL use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.