# sql server time compare with offset

Tags: sql-server, datetime, getdate

I've got a select query that returns a list of rows that have expired

```
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.myTable
  WHERE  endDate < Convert(datetime, Convert(int, GetDate()))
```

how can I get it to use current day at 2AM instead of the current time I get from `GetDate()`

Comment: You mean the timestamp for this morning at 2AM? Have you tried date_sub() or date_add()

Comment: yes, though I suppose I could pass it using the server-side language.

Comment: Can't you just get the current date at midnight and add 2Hours to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current day at 2AM:

```
convert(datetime,left(convert(varchar, getdate(), 121),10) + ' 02:00')
```

Comment: It's a format code. Have a look at http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx

Comment: @Daniel: Note that the [121 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx "CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)") is locale-dependent, even though it is the so called ODBC canonical format. It may well work with your locale settings, of course. Still, if you want it to be locale-independent, use the 112 format instead (and, accordingly, cut off 8 left characters instead of 10). Also, please pay attention to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1177449/297408 "Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server").