# SELECT WHERE Date = Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column of type dateTime. I want to do a query that selects all rows that take place on that date. Basically,

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE [timeStamp] = '02-15-2003'
```

But that only returns rows where [timeStamp] is '02-15-2003 00:00:00.000', but really I want rows from anytime that day.

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  PostgreSQL?

Comment: Strongly recommend you use yyyymmdd and not mm-dd-yyyy. Also suggest giving these a read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have indexes, you are going to want something which doesn't prevent the indexes from being used:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE [timeStamp] >= '20030215'
      AND [timeStamp] < '20030216'
```

You can do a truncation operation on the `[timeStamp]` column to get rid of any time part (implementation dependent), but this can potentially hurt the execution plan.  Unfortunately, you really have to look at the execution plan to see this, because sometimes the optimizer is clever about some functions and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Huraah! One correct answer at last. And have you thought about joining us here on dba.se? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap

Comment: Only suggested improvement I'd make is to correct the format - `mm-dd-yyyy` is not language/region safe. I know that's what the OP is using but maybe just needs a nudge.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I would love it if we would eventually get something to easily handle the various open/closed intervals - something like `datecol WITHIN [lower, upper)` because `BETWEEN` only handles `[]` - there's no concise handling of `()`, `[)`, and `(]`

Comment: Right, but the word BETWEEN is still ambiguous regardless of what syntax extensions you might add to it. People will still expect "between 1/1 and 1/2" to include all data for jan 1 and jan 2 (not ending at midnight on jan 2) and in plain English between is not always inclusive.

Answer (score 9):

You should CAST to DATE if you're on SQL 2008.

```
select * from [Table]
where cast([timeStamp] as date) = '02-15-2003'
```

[Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

--- UPDATE ---

The word the commenters should have used back in 2012 to describe why this is not the optimal solution is [sargability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Changing the data type in the WHERE clause, while the simplest solution, has implications for index usage that a bounded search would not.

Comment: No functions or CASTs on columns please. See number 2 here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

Comment: @gbn - You have a better suggestion?  Because there's really not that many ways to strip the time part off of a date in SQL Server, and this way is low friction and easy to type.  Always prefer practical over the academic.

Comment: @CadeRoux's answer is better. While I do like yours for SQL Server 2008 the open-ended range is a much safer standard for all versions and all date/time types.

Comment: To be explicit, the open-ended range is generally a better approach because the last approach you should be trying is applying any kind of operation on the base column when it can be avoided. In this case it's ok because SQL Server 2008+ will compensate for your error in the `date` case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

in sql server 2008 + :

```
  SELECT * FROM Table
        WHERE cast( [timeStamp] as date)  = '02-15-2003'
```

or

just ZERO the time part :  ( 2005+)

```
   SELECT * FROM Table
    WHERE DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, [timeStamp]), 0)  = '02-15-2003'
```

Comment: No functions or CASTs on columns please. See number 2 here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

Comment: @gbn the convert to DATE actually doesn't prevent an index from being used, but it should be noted that it doesn't hold true for all type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL 2014, this works perfect:

```
SELECT [YourDateColumn] FROM [YourTable] WHERE(DATEPART(dd,[YourDateColumn]) = '29')
```

Might have some performance issues on very large DB's.

Comment: doesn't answer the OP question, but is actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

try this.. SQL SERVER

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE convert(date,[timestamp]) = '2003-02-15'
```

should return all rows on the specified day.

Comment: try this and you'll see the result.

Comment: No functions or CASTs on columns please. See number 2 here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

Comment: Oh!!! You might as well tell microsoft to remove all functions. And do it yourself!

Comment: @Rhian A: Did you read the article? its not never use them, just don't use them on indexed columns becasue then you are no longer using the index.

Comment: @RhianA: What @gbn implies is that while the `function(columnX) = constant` will often not be able to use an index. But if you can rewrite as `columnX = reverse_function(constant)` it will. And therefore perform better.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored procedure that will accept "start date" and "end date"

In this case the start date and end date can be the same

This ensures that all rows from 12:01 AM to 11:59 PM are returned

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create PROCEDURE  TestBetweenDates
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StartDate DateTime = 0, 
    @EndDate DateTime = 0
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SET @StartDate = cast(Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, -6, @StartDate ), 101) + ' 12:01 AM' as datetime)

        SET @EndDate = cast(Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, -0, @EndDate), 101) + ' 11:59 PM' as datetime)

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE ([timeStamp] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) 


END
GO
```

Answer (score -6):

Date comparisons can be a tricky thing.

Remember that it is a datetime and not a string. This is why you got unexpected results.

For the specific query you have in mind, the appropriate query is

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE 0 = datediff(day,[timestamp],'02-15-2003')
```

You may also do compares by month() and year() which return integer values.

You usually have to write custom functions to get comparisons that are non-trivial.

Also note

```
WHERE 0 = datediff(day,[timestamp],'02-15-2003')
```

is much better than

```
WHERE datediff(day,[timestamp],'02-15-2003') = 0
```

The former does not interfere with internal efficiency while the latter does.

Comment: I have tested this and you are wrong. The order of clauses in the where does not affect performance. Without an index your version takes twice the amount of time compared to the answers provided by Cade Roux and mattmc3. The real difference in performance in a query like this is when using an index and both queries I mentions does a Index seek where both your queries have to do a full table scan. Until you can provide some tests or documentation that proves me wrong you have a -1 from me.

Comment: No functions or CASTs on columns please. See number 2 here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

Comment: If `WHERE a = b` behaves differently than `WHERE b = a` in any terms, result-wise, performance-wise or any other-wise, I want my money (for the SQL-Server licence) back.

Comment: @mikael - it is a known performance tweak to not put calculated values on the left side of the comparison.  as you can see from my profile, i really don't care about the point system - downvote away.

Comment: @mson: And I meant `WHERE a = whatever_complex_expression_or_function_b` compared to `WHERE whatever_complex_expression_or_function_b = a`

Comment: @mson You say "it's known" but we are telling you **we have tested** and it's not true.  There are more myths about SQL Server performance that refuse to die...

Comment: @jnk - i've seen the performance variance demonstrated in 2 different seminars and was able to see the performance improvement when i revised my queries.  perhaps, things have changed since sql server 2005, but i will verify again and post if there is no longer a difference.

Comment: @gbn yes, but if we have the freedom to assume things, why not create a computed column index - http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-indexed-computed-columns-to-improve-performance