# Convert DateTime SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to get only date and hours from datetime field. How do I do that?

My query:

```
select  ImpFile, convert(nvarchar,ImpDate,21) as ImpDate
from nol_artikula_izmaina
```

The output from this query:
[image: pic1]

What I need is that it only shows me the date and the hour for example the field ImpDate should look like this: 2012-05-11 14:00:00:000 and 2012-05-11 16:00:00:000

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works by getting the number of [whole] hours between "date 0" and `ImpDate`, then adding that to "date 0".

It's very similar in principle to [removing the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server) (which gets the number of [whole] days) and can be used to "truncate" to any date part (though for seconds or smaller, you may need to use a different "floor" date than 0 to avoid an overflow).

```
 SELECT ImpFile, DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, ImpDate), 0)
 FROM nol_artikula_izmaina
```

Answer (score 0):

Select using datepart.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(v=sql.80).aspx