# Getting DateRange between date part only sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to get records between dates taking into account only date part only? I mean getting only eg 2012-07-30

the following does not seem to work

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime,@NewStartDate dateTime
SET @StartDate='2012-06-03 17:43:56.220'
SET @EndDate='2012-07-30 00:00:00.000'

SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),StartDate,111) >=CONVERT(varchar(10),@StartDate,111)
AND CONVERT(varchar(10),EndDate,111) <=CONVERT(varchar(10),@EndDate,111)
```

Comment: use [DATEADD/DATEDIFF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server) to remove the time part of a date. Varchar conversion is inefficient. E.g. `DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))`. When you upgrade to SQL-Server 2008 or later you can use `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),111)
```

prints

```
2012/05/23
```

So it definitely strips the date part.
What makes you think your query "does not seem to work" ?

Comment: Not sure why i was getting something different.mmmm You are right it does work.Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your method works fine.  You could also use the method from GartethD's comment.  If you have version 2008, `cast(getdate() as date)` is definitely superior.