# SQL - Getting Data with Today's Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores people's orders, and within this table is a DateTime field. How can I get the information through a query, which includes only today's Date, without needing the time?

Comment: `WHERE DATE(DateTime) == TODAY()`

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? If SQL Server dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871824/73226

Comment: The RDBMS is MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, YourDateField) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't add a RDBMS - this solution works for MS SQL Server:

```
WHERE DATE(yourdatefield) = Convert(date, getdate())
```