# howto ASP.NET SQL query where DateTime greater than?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

On my asp.net project I use SQLDataSource to connect to a DB,
I want to filter rows with a DateTime field (PublishDate) from the last 7 days

(So I see books with PublishDate greater than DateTime.Now - 7 days)

you can see in the screen capture what I have so far

How can I do it in the query (without using code to go through lines and compare datetime)?

[image]

Comment: are you referring to a WHERE clause?  WHERE PublishDate >= GetDate()-7

Comment: @antisane I will add as an answer for you.

Comment: Watch out - GETDATE() includes current time, so if `PublishedDate` has time part you may not be getting all the books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to add a WHERE clause to your query:

```
WHERE PublishDate >= Getdate() -7
```

The `Getdate()` function returns both the date and the time. So if your PublishDate does not have the time you will need to plan for that in your query.

You can use the following to remove the time:

```
WHERE PublishDate > DATEADD (d, -7, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following WHERE clause

```
WHERE Books.PublishedDate > DATEADD (d, -7, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

just before ORDER BY.

For performance reasons I would suggest that `PublishedDate` is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

If PublishDate is DATETIME and you're storing ONLY date information or if you're column data type is DATE (SQL 2008), this will work:

```
select a.firstName, a.lastName, b.Name, b.PicturePath, b.PublishDate
from authors a
join books b on a.authorID = b.AuthorsID
where b.PublishDate > getdate() -7
order by b.PublishDate
```

However, if you ARE storing the time information and you only want to compare the date information, you'll have to truncate the time either from the left side, or the right side + 1 day:

For SQL 2008:

```
select a.firstName, a.lastName, b.Name, b.PicturePath, b.PublishDate
from authors a
join books b on a.authorID = b.AuthorsID
where cast(b.PublishDate as Date) > getdate() -7
order by b.PublishDate
```

For SQL 2005 and below:

```
select a.firstName, a.lastName, b.Name, b.PicturePath, b.PublishDate
from authors a
join books b on a.authorID = b.AuthorsID
where b.PublishDate > DATEADD (d, -8, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
order by b.PublishDate
```

There are several ways to truncate time:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
select DATEADD (d, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

See this SO question for truncating time:  [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

To include the 7th day, simply change > to >=

Comment: When you convert the getdate() to a varchar you should consider including the length of the date.

Comment: @bluefeet - convert(varchar) really isn't the best approach to begin with, but varchar has a default minimum of 30 when using cast or convert which is plenty of room for the date portion.

Comment: I agree it isn't the best approach but what I am saying is if you use it you should at least specify the length. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TSQL DATEDIFF function , for example :

```
SqlCommand comm=new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Borrow WHERE DATEDIFF(day,StartDate,EndDate) > 7");
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to do this:

```
select Authors.firstName,Authors.lastName,Books.Name,Books.PicturePath,
Books.PublishDate,
From Authors inner join Books
on Authors.authorId = Books.AuthorId
WHERE Book.PublishDate >= GETDATE() - 7
order by Books.PublishDate
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are using the query designer then you can pass the filters in filter fields. of query designer. as like in publishing data in filter box <'05/20/2012' or you can give there getdate() funcation of sql server. then minus the days you want.